# Bibliography entry out of alphabetical order with character Ş

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I'm pretty new to TeX so please forgive me if this requires just a simple solution. I'm writing a thesis that uses almost 100% English characters exclusively, except for a case where an author I cite has a Turkish name, starting with the letter Ş. I'm using `natbib` and `bibtex`, with the `bibliographystyle` = `chicago`.

I've gotten everything to work just as I want it, except in the bibliography the Turkish author's entry is not in alphabetical order, instead appearing between the letters C and E.

- Coleman, R. G. and X. Wang (1995). Overview of the Geology and Tectonics of UHPM. In R. G. Coleman and X. Wang (Eds.), Ultrahigh Pressure Metamorphism (1 ed.)., Chapter 1, pp. 1–32. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
- Şengor, A. M. C. and B. A. Natal’in (1996). Paleotectonics of Asia: fragments of a synthesis. In A. Yin and M. Harrison (Eds.), The Tectonic Evolution of Asia (1 ed.)., Chapter 21, pp. 486–640. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
- Ernst, W. G. and J. G. Liou (2008, November). High- and ultrahigh-pressure metamorphism: Past results and future prospects. American Mineralogist 93(11-12), 1771–1786.

I've read through everything I can think of at this point but I can't figure out why it's in that order and can't figure out how I can somehow customize it so that it shows up with the `S` authors. I know that there are suggestions to use `biblatex` and `biber`, but I am novice enough that I don't know if I can figure out how to get that to work (getting to this point where I am was difficult enough...). I even tried using the `key` field in the `.bib` file, but that was not successful. Here is the `.bib` entry:

```
@incollection{Sengor1996,
abstract = {},
address = {Cambridge},
author = {\c{S}eng\"{o}r, Ali Mehmet Cel\^{a}l and Natal'in, Boris A.},
booktitle = {The Tectonic Evolution of Asia},
chapter = {21},
edition = {1},
editor = {Yin, An and Harrison, Mark},
keywords = {Asia,cratons},
mendeley-tags = {Asia,cratons},
pages = {486--640},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
title = {{Paleotectonics of Asia: fragments of a synthesis}},
year = {1996}}
```

Any ideas for what I should try? I'm sure there is a solution but I'm not familiar enough with the system to know where it may lie. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just a short comment: Exactly because you're a novice you shouldn't bother with traditional `bibtex` and have instead a look at `biblatex/biber`. There's no reason to use outdated software when better alternatives already exist. Don't create a legacy problem for yourself if you don't have to. `biber` will deal with all Unicode characters without any problems.

Comment: I installed TeXShop to start with and try out this language - and I couldn't figure out how to use biblatex and biber. I hope to at some point though.

Comment: See also [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001).

Answer (score 9):

All special characters need to be grouped separately. As such, use

```
%...
author = {{\c{S}}eng{\"{o}}r, Ali Mehmet Cel{\^{a}}l and Natal'in, Boris A.},
%...
```

The reason for the misplaced sorting is because the sorting is probably based on `cSengor` (stripping all the "special stuff").

The following is taken verbatim from [BibTeX Tips and FAQ](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf) (p 6) - consider reading about half way down:

> **Q5: I am confused about the diﬀerence between special characters and the use of braces to protect text from case changes. Also, when should
>   I “shield” things with braces?**
>
> The rules that govern all this are simple, but confusing. BibTeX
>   considers everything within a `{\ .. }` construct at brace level 0
>   (and only brace level 0), that is the top level of bracing of the
>   field (which is not affected by whether quotes or braces are used to
>   delimit the entire field), to be a “special character” and will treat
>   is though the entire construct is a single character. Within special
>   characters, control sequences (LaTeX commands) will be preserved as
>   is, but all other text may be case changed or otherwise processed as
>   needed. Furthermore, within special characters, additional levels of
>   braces do not increment the brace level. On the other hand, `{ .. }`
>   constructs at brace level 0 (the key here is that a `\` does not
>   immediately follow the opening brace — if so, it would make it a
>   special character) do increment the brace level as well as do nested
>   braces within them. All text and control sequences at brace level 1 or
>   higher is protected from case changes or other processing.
>   It is
>   perhaps easier to understand from an example. Consider:
>
> ```
> title = "L0 {\relax S0 {S0 {S0}}} L0 {L1 {\relax L2 {L3}} L1} \LaTeX\ L0"
> ```
>
> where `Lx` indicates brace level `x` and `Sx` indicates a (part of a)
>   special character at brace level `x`. Again, nothing would change here
>   if braces had been used to delimit the entire field instead of quotes.
>   The three `S0`’s are all considered to be part of the same special
>   character because they are all within a `{\ .. }` construct at brace
>   level 0. Text at `S0` may be case changed, but the `\relax` as well as
>   other control sequences in `S0` will not be changed. Note that the
>   additional nested braces within the special character do not increment
>   the brace level. Thus, there is no such thing as `S1` or higher. The
>   first `L1` is at brace level 1 because it is a `{ .. }` (and not a
>   special character). Note that in this case, additional levels of
>   braces do increment the brace level counter. Furthermore, the second
>   `{\relax ..` is not treated as a special character because it occurs
>   at brace level 1. All characters and control sequences at `L1` and
>   higher will be protected from case changes. Note that in this example
>   the control sequence `\LaTeX` is subject to case changes. Thus, if the
>   bibstyle set the title to lowercase, the resultant `\latex` command
>   would likely generate an error.
>   With all this in mind, we can look
>   at some practical examples. Consider:
>
> ```
> title = "Secrets of {NASA}"
> ```
>
> `NASA` needs to be enclosed in braces because it is an acronym that
>   must remain in uppercase. Likewise, we usually need to protect math
>   from case changes:
>
> ```
> title = "The {$A_\beta$} Protocol"
> ```
>
> Simple argumentless LaTeX commands are also easily protected:
>
> ```
> title = "The {\LaTeX} Book"
> ```
>
> However, note that in this case, `\LaTeX` will be treated as a special
>   character and so the text “LaTeX” will not be considered when sorting.
>   Thus, in cases where the name of the LaTeX command is identical to the
>   text it represents, it may be better to use an extra set of braces so
>   that the letters that make up the command will be taken into
>   consideration when sorting:
>
> ```
> title = "The {{\LaTeX}} Book"
> ```
>
> [...]
>   Another application of brace shielding is with titles in
>   languages (such as German) in which title capitalization must be
>   preserved with some words (such as nouns and names):
>
> ```
> title = "{M}essung von {S}t{\"o}rfeldern an {A}nlagen
>          und {L}eitungen der {T}elekommunikation im
>          {F}requenzbereich 9 {kHz} bis 3 {GHz}",
> ```
>
> Note that `{\"o}` is treated as a special character and the “o” is not
>   protected against case changes. However, the first letter of the nouns
>   are protected because they are at brace level 1.
>   Things get a bit
>   more complicated when a LaTeX command has an argument. The correct
>   approach depends on whether the argument needs to be protected from
>   case changes. Consider:
>
> ```
> note = "Volume~2 is listed under Knuth \cite{TEX:book}"
> ```
>
> If the bibstyle changes the note ﬁeld to lowercase, we will get:
>
> ```
> volume~2 is listed under knuth \cite{TEX:book}
> ```
>
> so we will likely want to enclose first letter of Knuth’s last name in
>   braces. Furthermore, if we had an unusual bibstyle that rendered the
>   note field in uppercase, we would get:
>
> ```
> VOLUME~2 IS LISTED UNDER KNUTH \CITE{TEX:book}
> ```
>
> which would result in an error when the nonexistent `\CITE` is
>   executed. We might be tempted to try something like this:
>
> ```
> note = "Volume~2 is listed under Knuth {\cite}{TEX:book}"
> ```
>
> but this won’t work because the extra braces around the `\cite`
>   command will prevent it from seeing its argument:
>
> ```
> VOLUME~2 IS LISTED UNDER KNUTH {\cite}{TEX:book}
> ```
>
> Instead, we might try something like this:
>
> ```
> note = "Volume~2 is listed under {K}nuth {\cite{TEX:book}}"
> ```
>
> However, this is not safe either because the cite key “TEX:book” is
>   now considered to be part of a special character and so it may be case
>   changed (just like the second `S0` in the example before)! Therefore,
>   we need to employ an additional set of braces to get the `\cite`
>   command and its argument to brace level(s) greater than zero:
>
> ```
> note = "Volume~2 is listed under {K}nuth {{\cite{TEX:book}}}"
> ```
>
> so as to ensure everything will work regardless of what the bibstyle
>   does to the note field.
>   It is usually a good idea to let the `.bst`
>   file convert/format the fields as it sees fit — so don’t force things
>   with extra braces unless you have to. Future versions of BibTeX may be
>   more intelligent with respect to case changing and thus may require
>   fewer “manual interventions” with braces. [...]

Comment: I'm astounded, on the eve of 2012, that anyone can call "Ş" a "special character". Even if we don't yet have full support for sorting in national collating orders, I think it would be healthier to call it "Unsupported National", rather than "Special."

Comment: @Brent.Longborough - "Special character" is a set term in BibTeX. It means, for all intents and purposes, "any alphabetic character not included in the 7-bit ASCII table". No more, no less. (Of course, the fact that BibTeX still expects input to be 7-bit ASCII is, shall we say, troublesome...)

Answer (score 8):

The `author` field of the bib entry in your example code should look like this:

```
author = {{\c S}eng{\"o}r, Ali Mehmet Cel{\^a}l and Natal'in, Boris A.},
```

Compared with the form given in your example, the accented characters are "enclosed" in curly braces. With this change, the entry will be sorted under "Sengor".

Comment: I believe that Ş is not actually an "accented character", but is considered another character of the alphabet in its own right. Perhaps one of our Turkish friends could confirm or deny that.

Comment: It is, but in a document in English one would probably collate it together with "S".

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Indeed, it is included as a separate letter (U+015E). It is between S and T letter in the alphabetical order.

Comment: Worked like a charm - I am indebted! Excited to learn more and more about this language.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I remember the difficulty I had once, finding a word starting with "Ll" in my Spanish dictionary. Maybe the collating order doesn't depend only on the *(sub)language*, but also on the *audience*?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I'd say yes; while a paper by *Ångström* would be at the end of a list in a Swedish document, it should be among other "A" entries in an English (or Italian) one.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough - The term "accented character" is, again, straight out of BibTeX jargon. Any character that can be produced, in LaTeX, via some combination of a basic (7-bit) alphabetic character and one or more "accents" (including Umlauts, ogoneks, haceks, Polish soft-l's, angstrom, Danish o, etc etc) is called an "accented character" in BibTeX jargon.