# How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, accents, characters

How to write in bibliography (package natbib) letter "a" with two dots above? Specially, I mean the word Birkhäuser.

Is there a general rule or way how to write such umlauts or other accented letters in bibliographies?

Answer (score 573, accepted):

To typeset accented characters inside bibliography fields for processing with BibTeX, encase them in curly braces. To list but a few accented characters:

```
{\"a} {\^e} {\`i} {\.I} {\o} {\'u} {\aa} {\c c} {\u g} {\l} {\~n} {\H o} {\v r} {\ss} {\r u}
```

[image]

The word Birkhäuser should therefore be entered as `Birkh{\"a}user`.

Just to provide a somewhat more involved case: the name `Jaromír Kovářík` should be entered as either `Jarom{\'i}r Kov{\'a}{\v r}{\'i}k` or, more succinctly, `Jarom{\'i}r Kov{\'a\v r\'i}k`. As is explained in greater detail below, BibTeX will then sort the surname `Kovářík` as if it were spelled `Kovarik`, i.e., without any "accented characters". Replacing the accented characters in `Kovářík` with unaccented characters matters if the bibliography's entries are sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames and if the bibliography contains entries with the surnames Kovářík, Kovács, Kowalski, and Kowatski...

---

**Addendum**: There is an obvious follow-up question to the "**How** does one enter a special character for use in BibTeX?" question: **Why** is it necessary to encase these "special characters" in this manner? Or: **Why** are the ordinary methods of entering these characters in a LaTeX document -- say, `\"{a}` or `\"a`, let alone `ä` -- not quite right for BibTeX?

There are two separate reasons for this requirement.

1. If you use double-quotes, i.e., `" ... "`, to delimit the contents of a bibliographic field, you will find that writing

```
    author = "Anna H\"{a}user",
```

generates a BibTeX error, whereas

```
    author = "Anna H{\"a}user",
```

does not. I.e., BibTeX isn't quite smart enough on its own to distinguish between the two uses of the `"` character and needs extra help.

2. In addition, contents of bibliographic fields -- certainly the `author` and `editor` fields, but potentially other fields as well, including the `title`, `booktitle`, and `organization` fields -- are frequently used to *sort* entries alphabetically.

How do BibTeX (and LaTeX) sort characters with Umlaute, diacritics, and other special features relative to the basic 26 characters of the Latin alphabet? How is one supposed to sort three authors named, say, `Peter Hauser`, `Anna Häuser`, and `John Hill`? For some pretty sound reasons -- but which are way too ancient and obscure to go into any adequate level of detail here; to explore these reasons properly, it's crucial to have Appendix C of the TeXBook handy... -- a decision was made in the design of BibTeX to "purify" (the BibTeX function that does this job really is called `purify$`!) the contents of various fields as follows (this method conforms, probably not surprisingly, to US and UK sorting criteria; it needn't be "correct" outside of English-speaking regions, as I will note below) *for sorting purposes*:

- `{\"a}`, `{\'a}`, `{\^a}`, etc are all made equivalent to `a`,
- `{\"o}`, `{\'o}`, `{\H o}` and `{\o}` are all made equivalent to `o`,
- `{\l}` and `{\L}` become equivalent to `l` and `L`, respectively,
- `{\ss}` becomes equivalent to `ss`,
- `{\aa}` becomes equivalent to `aa`,
- and so on for all other "accented" characters,
- finally, any characters that do not fit into this scheme, including `ä`, are moved to the very end, i.e., *after `z`*. This may seem arbitrary and ill-informed from today's vantage point, but back when BibTeX was created more than 20 years ago the only relevant character encoding and sorting system was ASCII.

As you can immediately appreciate, this "purification" step is greatly simplified and made more robust if the "accented" characters are all entered consistently in the manner suggested in the first part of this answer.

Turning to the earlier case of the three authors named `Peter Hauser`, `Anna Häuser`, and `John Hill`: How will they appear in a bibliography whose entries are sorted alphabetically by the authors' surnames? If Anna's last name is entered as `H{\"a}user`, the three authors will end up being listed as `Häuser, A.` - `Hauser, P.` - `Hill, J.`. In contrast, if Anna's last name had been entered as `Häuser`, the sorting order would have been Hauser - Hill - Häuser. For most English-speaking readers, the second ordering will look completely wrong.

Some specialists from, say, Sweden, may object that this approach to sorting characters that aren't among the basic 26 characters of the Latin alphabet doesn't meet the specific national standards of, say, Sweden. [I obviously don't mean to pick on any Swedes. I mention them because I remember having read somewhere that in the Swedish alphabet, `ä` does come *after* `z` and hence is definitely *not* equivalent (not even for sorting purposes!) to `a`.] My answer to this objection is: If you're a Swedish author writing in Swedish for a Swedish target audience, you had better conform to specific Swedish customs. On the other hand, if you're a Swede writing in English in a journal that's exclusively published in English, it'll do you no good at all if you try to insist on obeying Swedish sorting customs in your paper's bibliography. Of course, the very inability of BibTeX to be easily adaptable to non-English sorting customs is one of the reasons for the development and adoption of BibLaTeX and Biber. However, that's a topic for another day, isn't it?

The issue of how BibTeX sorts bibliographic entries (as well as many other fascinating [!] issues) is examined at length and explained admirably in the surprisingly readable (given the enormous dryness of the subject!) essay [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast) by Nicolas Markey. If you have TeXLive or MikTeX as your TeX distribution, you can also access this document by typing "texdoc tamethebeast" at a command prompt.

---

For the sake of completeness and replicability, here's the MWE that gives to the screenshot shown above. Note that it's not necessary to load any extra packages to typeset the accented characters considered in this example. However, assuming you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, you will need to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1` if you need to typeset, say, an ogonek-accented character, such as `{\k a}`, or the Icelandic "thorn", `{\th}`.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
{\"a} {\^e} {\`i} {\.I} {\o} {\'u} {\aa} {\c c} {\u g} {\l} {\~n} {\H o} {\v r} {\ss} {\r u}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I expanded the scope of the question, but as far as I can see, your answer covers it all already.

Comment: @Mico: Where would I find a comprehensive list of all character macros and their unicode equivalents?

Comment: @Mico: Done. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64009/8057

Comment: Great answer.  Completely correct about the Swedish usage of å, ä, and ö (they come after z).

Comment: @Mico Learner's Q: could you show me with an example where [Dror's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57827/15717) fails  while using `bibtex`, When i run it with `bibtex` the ouput gave accentuated characters with `utf8` inputencoding

Comment: @texenthusiast - The issue with using natively accented characters in BibTeX (though not in `bibtexu` or `biber`) is that the sorting will be affected by the presence of non-ASCII characters: Most readers, at least most readers from English-speaking regions, will think something's wrong if the entries of authors whose surname starts with `G` are sorted `Galbraith` `Golosov` `Gustafsson` `Gödel`. (Scandinavia-based readers, on the other hand, might be delighted by this ordering...)

Comment: Just to add a reference link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes

And the note: This does not work with MathJax, unfortunately.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV - I'm not sure the link you've provided is a good reference for the purpose of entering "special" characters in BibTeX entries. In particular, the codes suggested in the link are *not* correct if they're to be used with BibTeX. Incidentally, I don't "get" your comment about MathJax -- the posting was about BibTeX, not MathJax, right?

Comment: Sorry Mico. First thing that pops up in Google Search if you enter "umlaute in tex" is this site, I scammed the text and did not catch the "BibTeX" part, just the "Tex" part. So this info is for all who run into the same problem.

Comment: How about á, í?, I tried `{\'{a}}`, `{\'a}` and `\'{a}`. None of those worker, what should I try? (I do not want to use `inputenc`).

Comment: @Hans - Have you tried `{\'a}` and `{\'i}`?  If that doesn't work, you're probably using an unusual font. Please advise as to which document class and which font-related packages you use.

Comment: @Mico Yes sir, I have tried those, no special font, I am doing it in IEEEtran article document. I don't want to post a full question to get it closed as duplicate. By the way, I am working in Overleaf, if that matters at all.

Comment: @Hans - Not knowing more about your document setup, I really don't know what to recommend, except that you post a new query in which you explain everything you're doing (including the fact that you're working in Overleaf). Sorry I can't give any more directly useful advice.

Comment: What about a single dot in an uppercase letter???

Comment: @SibaMishra - Why the triple question marks?! Does the fourth entry in the screenshot near the top of this answer work for you?

Comment: It was my mistake. @Mico. You are right, I have tried your suggested answer, but why the same is not compatible with Springer template?

Comment: @SibaMishra = *Which* Springer template? There are several out there...

Comment: \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}  is the document class name.

Comment: @SibaMishra - I experience no problems at all with `{\.I}` -- or, for that matter, any other "accented" characters written in the manner I recommend in my answer -- when using the `svjour3` document class.

Comment: +1: Entertaining to read!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Many thanks for the compliment! Yeah, for some reason, this is my most-upvoted answer. Very nice to know that it's entertaining to read. :-)

Answer (score 62):

When using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you can have it directly.

Consider the following `.bib` file:

```
@BOOK
  {Goe,
   AUTHOR  = "Gödel",
   TITLE   = "Die Vollständigkeit der Axiome des logischen Funktionenkalküls.",
   PUBLISHER = "Monatshefte für Mathematik und Physik",
   YEAR = 1930
  }
```

for example. Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\section{Introduction}
Hällo Wörld\cite{Goe}

\bibliography{encodingInBib}

\end{document}
```

yields the desired result. Or, you could also use `biblatex` and the following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\bibliography{ref}
\begin{document} 
Hällo Wörld\cite{Goe} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the final result, using either method, the umlauts are inserted automatically.

Comment: You may want to state a bit more prominently that this method requires the use of `biblatex`. The OP provided the tag "bibtex" rather than "biblatex", and hence it may be worth pointing out your method's requirement explicitly.

Comment: @Mico: Well as far as I see the `biblatex` is not the trick rather `inputenc`. Unless I missed something.

Comment: @Dror: `bibtex` won't sort this correctly (Gödel should be sorted as Godel).

Comment: @Caramdir: Depends on the language, in Finnish, for example, it wouldn't be sorted that way.

Comment: @morbusg - I guess Caramdir was assuming implicitly that the publication in question is written in English for an English language speaking target audience. For someone accustomed to English-language sorting rules, it would look very wrong indeed (and probably downright weird as well) to see `Gödel` sorted after, say, `Gyntelberg`.

Comment: @Mico: Sure, and you nicely covered this is your addendum, thanks `:-)`

Comment: It would be really helpful if some kind fellow could update this answer for XeLaTeX too, because that does not support `inputenc`.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta For XeLaTeX just encode the documents in `utf8` and make sure you load `fontspec` so you get a font that has the accented characters, e.g. `\usepackage{fontspec}` will be enough, as this loads `lmodern`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is what worked for me:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This package uses 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs covering the letter you mentioned (and much more)

Comment: The question is about the input, not the font.

Comment: I agree, but when I tried the package mentioned in the other answer, it did not resolve my issue. This package did. If you think my answer is not relevant/related to the question, please let me know so that I delete it.

Comment: Loading the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages (with suitably chosen options) will help on the LaTeX side of things. However, it does nothing on the BibTeX side of things. The current query is about how accented characters should be entered so that they'll get processed correctly by BibTeX; here, "processed correctly" includes *sorting*. As I wrote in my answer, in your setup, "Anna Häuser" would get sorted *after* "Brent Hauser". That goes against well-established (English language) sorting conventions, in which `Häuser` and `Hauser` are equivalent, so that "Anna" should come before "Brent".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will apply here, but in my case, I use Zotero to produce my bib file. I had trouble exporting it with accents and I didn't want to go through all the articles to write the accents as proposed in the answer.

I found that exporting the BibTeX file with character encoding as "Unicode (UTF-8 withou BOM)" worked, instead of "Unicode (UTF-8)". Now I can add new articles and export them without a problem!

Comment: While this approach may appear to "work", in the sense that Zotero now outputs something that is handled correctly by BibTeX and/or LaTeX, it doesn't address the issue of what do with non-ASCII characters such as ä, ö, é, and è *if* they occur in fields relevant for sorting. E.g., if your bibliography has two entries, authored by Anna Häuser and Peter Hauser, respectively, then your approach will lead BibTeX to place the Hauser entry before the Häuser entry. If your document is written in English, this ordering would be deemed wrong because "Peter" should come after "Anna".

Answer (score -1):

I used Mendeley as my .Bib generator, just check the "Escape LaTeX special characters(#{}%& etc.)" on the Mendeley > Tools > Option > 'BibTeX' tabs.

Then back to the LaTeX, recompile and done.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, your answer is wrong, for two separate reasons. First, it doesn't actually address the question, which was about entering "accented" characters such as `ä`, `ö`, `é`, `è`, and `ß`. The question was *not* about characters, such as `#`, `%`, and `&`, which are "special" to TeX. Second, it's wrong to escape characters such as `%` and `&` if they occur in a URL string, as escaping these characters would change the actual URL strings. URL strings should be either encased in a `\url{...}` "wrapper" or occur in a field called `url`, so that no escaping is needed.

Comment: The queries and answers posted on TeX.SE are frequently brought up in Google searches, and many readers rely heavily (and possibly uncritically) on the answers they find here. That's why it's important to be precise in one's answers. I certainly hope that you didn't perceive my comments to be harsh. You are definitely very welcome to post more answers in the future.

Comment: Thanks sir, I understood. I've been being a silent reader for a long time, but then I found the solution but it was a mistake that my solution isn't the proper answer for this problem. So I need to adapt this kind of situation, because its uncommon situation for me to answer on this TeX.SE.

Answer (score -1):

\usepackage{lifecon} then \ddot{a} gives a umlaut. This is a symbol in actuarial mathematics (lifecon as in lifecontingencies). I quote from a previous answer on stack exchange,"That package doesn't seem to be part of the major TeX distributions, but you can find a copy of it in the lifecontingencies repository on GitHub."

Comment: Welcome. A link? A quote maybe?

Comment: While this might work, it does not really print an ä, but a mathematical symbol which just happens to look very similar. So I personally would not recommend doing this.

Answer (score -2):

One hack for Latex is to use simply `\ddot`:

```
$$ \ddot{a} $$
```

Renders as:

[image: umlaut latex]

Only draw back: It does not work within `\text{}`.

So `G\ddot{a}rtner` works but not `\text{G\ddot{a}rtner}`.

Comment: I am not sure that (ab)using math-mode to print regular text is a good idea. Also, you should definitely *not* use `$$`.

Comment: A workaround is better than nothing. In Latex you can use `$$` or `\(  \)`. In the end, you can stick with `ae` instead of `ä` if your readers are okay with it.

Comment: Maybe, but note https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/47927