# necessity of braces for accent commands

Tags: braces, grouping

Many resources on LaTeX teach that "é" and "ä" are typeset with (respectively) `\'{e}` and `\"{a}`; and it is similar for other accent symbols. Are the braces really needed? Aren't `\'e` and `\"a` shorter but identical in functionality?

Comment: With the right packages you can even type them in directly using your keyboard (or copy&paste).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The manuals usually insist teaching a uniform syntax: all arguments will be braced. However, as far as TeX is concerned, a one letter (one token, to be precise) argument can in most cases be left without braces:

```
\"{a} \"a
```

will give exactly the same result. Not that I recommend it, but also

```
\begin{tabular}c
```

will result in a one column `tabular`, just like `\begin{tabular}{c}`. The braces for accented letters are really handy for `\c` or `\v`: writing

```
gar\c con
```

is clumsy and `gar\c{c}on` is better. However, accents are more easily input using `inputenc` facility. It's way easier to encode our documents with UTF-8, declaring

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and then writing

```
garçon élève flügel čaj
```

The precise rule is:

> when TeX is looking for an argument to a macro defined with `\newcommand`, if it finds a left brace `{`, then the argument will be whatever is between this brace and the corresponding `}` (at the same level); otherwise the first token (character or control sequence) will be the argument.

This explains why one can omit the first pair of braces in

```
\newcommand\foo{something}
```

which is perfectly equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\foo}{something}
```

Of course this is *not* valid for optional arguments, which always need to be enclosed in brackets `[...]`.

Note: for BibTeX the situation is different (as nicely explained by Mico).

Answer (score 12):

For bibliographies at least -- more specifically, for files that will be processed by BibTeX at some point -- it's very important to write the accented characters as `{\'e}` and `{\"a}` rather than as `\'{e}` and `\"{a}` (or, for that matter, as `\'e` and `\"a`).

For other examples of how to render accented characters in a manner that's robust to BibTeX's requirements see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/5001) (shameless self-citation alert!).

Comment: Unfortunately, kerning is inhibited with `{\"a}` and friends unless you are using LuaTeX.

Comment: @mhp: I guess one's facing a choice between two negatives (when using BibTeX): either forego accented characters, or put up with some instances of less-than-optimal kerning of character pairs. Confronted with this choice, I suppose most users will put up with the latter, right?

Comment: Yes, undoubtedly.

Comment: You can type e.g. {T\^y} which I think should maintain kerning. But this is problematic if T would affect the sort order. EDIT: That is, you can put the whole word in curly brackets (T\^y) rather than just the accented character (\^y).