# Accent Commands Interpreted as Internal Bibtex Commands

Tags: bibtex, accents

I am having trouble with putting accent marks in my entries in my .bib references file.  There are two problems:

1) The author of one of my works has a tilde (~) over one letter in his name; the code I have for the "name" field in this entry is:

```
NAME = "Praj\{~}n\={a}karamati",
```

to get "Prajñākaramati."

When I compile the document, a "runaway argument" error comes up; it says `Paragraph ended before \name was complete.`  Looking at it now, I see that in the .bbl file the tilde is used to split first and last names within bibtex, here is the code from the .bbl file:

```
\entry{BCAPoussin}{book}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {{n}\={a}karamati}{n.}%
     {Praj\}{P.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \name{editor}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Vall\'{e}e~Poussin}{V.~P.}%
     {Louis}{L.}%
     {de~la}{d.~l.}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {Asiatic Society of Bengal}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{nP1}
  \strng{fullhash}{nP1}
  \field{sortinit}{N}
  \field{subtitle}{{Praj\~{n}\={a}karamati's commentary to the
  Bodhicary\={a}vat\={a}ra of \c{C}\={a}ntideva}}
  \field{title}{{Bodhicary\={a}vat\={a}rapa\~{n}jik\={a}}}
  \field{volumes}{4}
  \list{location}{1}{%
    {Calcutta}%
  }
  \field{year}{1914}
\endentry
```

Somehow it interpreted the "~" character, which was intended to accent an "n", as some kind of name break command.

2) Whenever I put an umlaut, which is done using a double quotation mark, (e.g. f\"{u}r for für) in a bibliography entry, it interprets it as the end of the entry, which is indicated by a quotation mark.

Does anyone know how to get bibtex to interpret these commands as accents and not internal bibtex commands?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use directly Unicode characters? Biber has no problem with them. In any case it should be `Praj{\~{n}}{\={a}}karamati`

Comment: What do you mean?  I am rather new to LaTeX.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: sorry, I just found the answer to this question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63324/necessity-of-braces-for-accent-commands).

Comment: biber, together with biblatex, is a complete alternative to bibtex which removes many of its limitations. One of these is that it expects, by default, unicode input which means that you can type e.g. Tŷ in your .bib file and biber and biblatex will be quite happy. (Actually I find biblatex/biber doesn't much like traditionally input accented characters but I've not bothered to investigate why.) biblatex/biber is a lot more flexible if this is an option.

Comment: @cfr -- See option `bibencoding` for `biblatex`