# Spell checking considering latex umlauts in .tex files

Tags: editors, characters, spelling

To make it short. My problem is this:

**content of .tex file**

```
Priorit"at is a german noun and means priority.
```

compare: `\"a` or `{\"a}`

**it results in**

```
Priorität is a german noun and means priority.
```

My spell checker (*notepad++* /w *aspell* plugin) then complains,
because it doesn't know `Priorit` and `at`. It doens't seem to recognize the
whole word.

I want to automate the spellchecking process, since I have a certain amount of .tex files
containing umlauts.

Comment: An idea would be to concatenate all files, replace the tex umlauts with uft8 chars and perform the spellchecking thereon.

Comment: `echo \`find . -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} +\` | sed 's/"u/ü/g; s/"U/Ü/g; s/"a/ä/g; s/"A/Ä/g; s/"o/ö/g; s/"O/Ö/g; s/"s/ß/g' >> all` but I still have to write back the changes.

Comment: Having replaced `"u` with `ü`, etc., you can keep those characters in your `.tex` file. See my answer below.

Comment: This approach changes the prerequisites. I'm still hoping that there is a solution to the problem in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your preamble, you can have umlauts and so on directly in your `.tex` files. I haven't used `\"a` to make an umlaut for ages - I just write `ä` directly in my `.tex` file.

---

**Note.** Within BibTeX files, you should revert to `\"a`, for the reason explained here: [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/25356)

Comment: You can't with `latin1` input enc. I had problems with uft8 on cygwin, and since I also edit the files under osx I'd preferably stick to latin1.

Comment: There's also `utf8x`. I don't understand the difference, but that's the one I use on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied, but here's my tentative solution

```
cd sources/
echo `find . -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} +` | sed -e 's/"u/ü/g; s/"U/Ü/g; s/"a/ä/g; s/"A/Ä/g; s/"o/ö/g; s/"O/Ö/g; s/"s/ß/g' -e "s/\\\'{e}/é/g" >> all
aspell -t -c all
```

But as `aspell` corrects the files interactively, you have to transfer the changes to the original `.tex` files.

**EDIT**

You can use following command to get a list with all spelling errors

```
echo `find . -name '*.tex' -exec cat {} +` | sed -e 's/"u/ü/g; s/"U/Ü/g; s/"a/ä/g; s/"A/Ä/g; s/"o/ö/g; s/"O/Ö/g; s/"s/ß/g' -e "s/\\\'{e}/é/g" | cat | aspell -t list
```

Answer (score 0):

The following LaTeXspellcheck.sh bash-script might be helpful as it automatically replaces the typical e.g. \"u or {\ss} umlauts so that aspell works as usual. After the spell check the revised file will be translated back to the \"u format and compared to the original file. Here all changes can be accepted individually with [space] or all together with [CTL-A]. [CTL-S] saves the changes.

Note that the call of "kompare" is just a check if all translations worked fine. If you are sure about it, the original file might simply be replaced, but that is on own risk.

```
#!/bin/bash
#usage: LaTeXspellcheck.sh de_DE LaTeXdatei.tex
#usage: LaTeXspellcheck.sh en_US LaTeXfile.tex

#create two tempfiles in the temp-folder and label them with the script's name
skriptname=`basename "$0"`
skriptnameOhneEndung=${skriptname%.*}
tempfile="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/${skriptnameOhneEndung}.temp"
rm -f $tempfile
touch $tempfile
tempfilezwo="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/${skriptnameOhneEndung}.temp2"
rm -f $tempfilezwo
touch $tempfilezwo

#translate umlauts from LaTeX to normal
cat $2 | sed 's/\\"a/ä/g' | sed 's/\\"o/ö/g' | sed 's/\\"u/ü/g' | sed 's/\\"A/Ä/g' | sed 's/\\"O/Ö/g' | sed 's/\\"U/Ü/g' | sed 's/{\\ss}/ß/g' | sed 's/\\-//g' > $tempfile

#spell check and write the result back to the tempfile
aspell -t -l $1 -c $tempfile

#translate umlauts from normal to LaTeX and save them in a second temp file
cat $tempfile | sed 's/ä/\\"a/g' | sed 's/ö/\\"o/g' | sed 's/ü/\\"u/g' | sed 's/Ä/\\"A/g' | sed 's/Ö/\\"O/g' | sed 's/Ü/\\"U/g' | sed 's/ß/{\\ss}/g' > $tempfilezwo

#compare the result with the original file
#just for checking if all translations are fine
#accept changes individually with space or all together with CTL-A.
#finally save changes with CTL-S
kompare $tempfilezwo $2
```