# How can I use accents (like \"{o}) in \footnote?

Tags: bibtex, footnotes, citing, accents, revtex

I get following error when I use in my tex file `\footnote{Shr\"{o}dinger}`. When I change to `\footnote{Shrodinger}` there is no error. Can you give me an advice what should I do? I use BiBTeX for bibliographies.

```
Runaway argument?
{Shr\}\BibitemShut {NoStop}\bibitem [{Note2()}]{Note2}\BibitemOpen \bibinfo \ET
C.
! File ended while scanning use of \@firstofone.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.665 \bibliography{mybib}
                         {}
?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We need a [minimal (non) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with, in order to understand what's going on. Are you sure it is `\footnote` or is it `\cite`?

Comment: Clearly you are not telling us the whole story, since if you make a document with simply `\footnote{Schr\"{o}dinger}` in it it compiles properly. And the error you are getting relates to the bibliography, so you need to show how you are producing your bibliography.

Comment: I think, this will work: `\footnote{Shr{\"{o}}dinger}`. If not fixed, MWE is required.

Comment: My guess is that there is a confusion of `\footnote` and `\footcite`.

Comment: Thank you, Jagath AR, the extra {} in \footnote{Shr{\"{o}}dinger} solved the problem.

Comment: The form `Schr{\"o}dinger` should always work, both in ordinary text and in footnotes. No need to place another set of curly braces around the `o` in `{\"o}`.

Comment: Thank you @Mico . I am new on site, what should I do to mark the question answered?

Comment: @eRic - I've posted an explicit answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what's going on since your description of the problem doesn't state whether the word in question is an argument of an explicit `\footnote` command or of something else, such as `\footcite`. At any rate, the problem seems to arise in connection with a citation, however generated.

The simplest solution, I think, is to write `Schr{\"o}inger`. Placing an additional set of curly braces around the `o` in `{\"o}` isn't necessary.

For much more information on how to enter "accented" characters in bibliographic entries, I suggest you read the question "[How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)" and the associated answers.

---

*Addendum*: In a comment to this answer, the OP mentioned that he/she uses the "Revtex" document class. This document class appears to introduce some (fairly unusual) interactions between material created with `\footnote` commands and the work of BibTeX. This would explain why the OP is encountering the baffling error message he/she reports when using the `\footnote` command with an argument that contains an accented character.

Comment: I just use in the main text \footnote{This is an approximate solution to the Schr{\"o}dinger equation ....} as it is suggested here http://publish.aps.org/files/revtex/apsguide4-1.pdf page 4 bullet 3. I don't use \footcite. Thank you.

Comment: @eRic - Thanks for providing this additional information, about using RevTeX4.1 as your document class. From my understanding of the package's user guide, it looks like the `revtex` document class has created some unexpected -- though not necessarily faulty! -- interactions between `\footnote` and various citation-related activities. Using the BibTeX-safe way of entering accented letters thus seems to be the way to go for dealing with these characters in footnotes.

Answer (score 4):

This is a clear bug in `revtex4-1` or, at least, in its documentation.

It should *always* be possible to type `\"{o}` or `\"o` in order to get `ö` in text, but the problem is that footnotes are translated (wrongly) into BibTeX input for being typeset in the bibliography (the reason why this is done is, to me, very obscure).

Remedies: either use the BibTeX convention, that is,

```
Schr{\"o}dinger
```

or use direct input of the accented character, with `inputenc`:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\footnote{Schr{\"o}dinger}

\footnote{Schrödinger's cat}
\end{document}
```

The second form is, in my opinion, preferable.

Please note two things:

1. Add the relevant information to your questions; the document class in use is always important to know.
2. The correct spelling is “Schrödinger” with a "c".

Comment: +1 for reminding people to always provide all relevant document-related information, such as the document class in use, when posting a question.

Comment: Is the cat alive? `:)`