# Special font in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

How can I use these references in my bibliography? When I create my bibliography, it change the font of special A' or...., how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you edit your question to elaborate, or even better, point out on the image what you'd like changed? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would also help us help you. `:-)`

Comment: Does the answer here help you?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/47522  Possible duplicate

Comment: An MWE will be crucial since we don't know how you are managing the rest of your references and the answer to your question will depend on that, among other things. While @cslstr may be right that the answer there will help, do note that it will only help if you are using `bibtex`. If you are using `biblatex` or if you are including your references directly in your document, the answer will be different.