# How to type diacritical marks over the letters 'r' and 'i' in latex?

Tags: tex-core, overleaf

I want to learn how to type diacritical marks over 'r' and 'i' in latex. I need to write a name of Czech Republic origin. The diacritical mark over 'r' looks like a small 'v' on the head of the 'r' and the diacritical sign above 'i' looks like a mirror image of the symbol `

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181384/diacritics-above-dotted-i-i-with-tittle

Comment: Welcome to the site! Since it’s not really clear from the link provided: the simplest approach is just to type the character into your UTF-8 document. If you’re compiling in PDFTeX, normalize your source file to NFC and include the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, it should just work, but you might need `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: You can use `\'{i}` for í and `\v{r}` for ř. As mentioned by @Davislor, however, it is probably easier to use the `fontenc`-package (maybe in combination with the `inputenc`-package) to type the characters directly in the TeX source.

Comment: @RenéB.Christensen Someone might still need `inputenc` (or `luainputenc`) to compile a document originally written in a different encoding, such as CP1250. Even then, it might be advisable to use `selinput`, so that the document will just work no matter how it is re-encoded. I would recommend that any new document be saved as UTF-8, which has been the default LaTeX encoding since 2018.

Comment: You can write ř or í.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful comments!

Comment: I've been using `\"o` or `\'i` quite a lot, but got stuck on `\vr`.  Took me too long to realize the brackets were needed `\v{r}`.  This was all to write the name `Anton\'in Dvo\v{r}\'ak`.  Not sure why, but I'm still using `pdflatex` which doesn't support `fontspec`.