# How to give BibTeX author names with diacritics and hyphen?

Tags: bibtex, symbols, hyphenation

I am trying to give a bibtex record for an author whose name contains

- a diacritic and
- a hyphen.

You may take this name as an example:

```
Klopotsko Müller-Wachtendonk
```

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745) I should give the `ü` as `{\"u}`. Furthermore, since the name has a hyphen, I need to put the last name in brackets to prevent `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` from incorrectly labeling a book authored by that person as [MW14] instead of [Mül14] (at least, that is the only way I know of to prevent the incorrect label).

However, if I give the author as

```
author = {Klopotsko {M{\"u}ller-Wachtendonk}}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
! Argument of \T1\" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{{M{\"}}14}
```

So, how do I have to give an author name with a diacritic and a hyphen such that

- BibTeX is able to sort correctly and
- bib-style alpha builds the correct label?

Minimum (not) working example:

test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\cite{phd/MW2014}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{test}{}

\end{document}
```

test.bib

```
@phdthesis{phd/MW2014,
  author    = {Klopotsko M{\"u}ller-Wachtendonk},
  title     = {Das Bild h{\"a}ngt schief},
  year      = {2014}
}
```

Comment: A workaround seems to be bracing only the hyphen: `M{\"u}ller{-}Wachtendonk`

Comment: A very simple way is to use `biblatex` and type directly `Klopotsko Müller-Wachtendonk` in utf8 format and use `biber` which knows about utf8, rather than `bibtex`.

Comment: @egreg: Great, didn't know about that. I tested and it works fine for me, thanks! If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bernard: True, but in my application I have to go completely old-school, with bibtex and plain ASCII bibtex data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order for a compound name to be considered a single token as far as `abbrv.bst` is concerned, it's sufficient to hide the hyphen:

```
@phdthesis{phd/MW2014,
  author    = {Klopotsko M{\"u}ller{-}Wachtendonk},
  title     = {Das Bild h{\"a}ngt schief},
  year      = {2014}
}
```

Note that the entry is missing the `school` field (not required, but important for indentification).

[image]