# Automatic hyphenatation of first names in BibTex

Tags: bibtex, hyphenation

I would like to create *BibTeX* entries that lead to the proper typesetting of hyphenated author first names under \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} that will nevertheless yield full printed names under other bibliography styles.  For instance, given the following author entry:

```
AUTHOR = "Soon-{W}ook Chung and Byoung-{K}wang Kim and Woo-{J}in Song"
```

the typeset reference under *IEEEtrans* *should* be

```
S.-W. Chung, B.-K. Kim and W.-J. Song, ....
```

(but it is not) and in a full bibliography style (e.g., for a book) the typeset reference should be

```
Soon-Wook Chung, Byoung-Kwong Kim and Woo-Jin Song, ....
```

I have tried numerous arrangements of brackets and hyphens (such as the one above) but no single entry gives the proper typesetting in *both* these bibliography styles.

How should I write the *BibTeX* entry (preferably without having to write special-purpose macros)?

I am running *TeXShop* 3.74 on a Mac.

This question is related to ones addressing hyphenation of [*last* names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98873/how-to-hyphenate-a-reference-that-has-a-lastname-with-a-hyphen?rq=1) and [dacritics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199704/how-to-give-bibtex-author-names-with-diacritics-and-hyphen?rq=1) but of course the answers to those questions are not quite appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf), BibTeX already takes care of hyphenated first names. Quoting the section about author names (p. 24):

> Names are separated by spaces above, but it may occur that two first names are separated by a hyphen, as in “Jean-François” for instance. BibTeX splits that string, and if both parts are in the First, the abbreviated surnames is “J.-F.” as (generally) wanted.

And indeed, simply typing the names with a hyphen and without any extra braces works fine, as shown by the following sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{hyphens.bib}
@article{hyphens,
  author = {Soon-Wook Chung and Byoung-Kwang Kim and Woo-Jin Song},
  title = {{Hyphenation of first names in Bib\TeX}},
  journal = {{The \TeX\ StackExchange}},
  year = 2016
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{hyphens}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{hyphens}

\end{document}
```

Output with bibliography style `plain`:

[image: Reference in plain style]

Output with bibliography style `IEEEtran`:

[image: Reference in IEEEtrans style]

Comment: Simpler than I thought!  +1