# Norwegian letters in bibliography and article text

Tags: bibtex, texniccenter, jabref, scandinavian-letters

I'm trying to write an article in English with some Norwegian names in it, both in the article itself as well as in the bibliography (bibtex).

Strangely, I don't get the display of the Norwegian letters right.

When I use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
```

I get the letters right in the text but not in bibliography.

When I use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
```

the letters are correctly dispayed in the bibliography but not in article text. The use of `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}` does not seem to help in either case.

I can remember having used only

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

once which had worked fine so I really cannot explain these strange results...

I'm using windows 7, MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnic Center 2.0 beta.

Any suggestions what might be wrong or what I should check?

Comment: when you changed to `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` did you also re-encode your document to latin1 from utf-8? But anyway better probably is to use and declare utf-8 but use traditional ascii markup in the bib file so `{\"o}` etc rather than using the letter directly.

Comment: You've tagged the posting with "biblatex", but in the first paragraph of your posting you state that you use "bibtex". Which program do you use? (bibtex and biblatex are *not* synonyms.) If you use bibtex, do check out the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: You can use `bibtex8` instead of `bibtex`. `bibtex8` provides support for unicode characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you very much! Both solutions work fine. 1) encoding the document in latin1 or 2) using ascii markup of Norwegian letters in bibliography and utf-8 encoding.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry for that. I use bibtex ;)

Comment: @Aki: `biber` understands `utf8`, so you can type norwegian letters directly (ask `JabRef` to save the .bib file in utf8 encoding).

Comment: @Guido - A minor point: `bibtex8` can handle 8-bit (1 byte) encoded characters (which suffices for most languages of European origin), but not "real" Unicode-based encodings (such as utf8, which encodes characters using up to 4 bytes of data). There is a program called `bibtexu`, but I've never used it and don't know how stable and reliable it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you changed to

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

You also need to re-encode your document to latin1 from utf-8.

But anyway better probably is to use and declare utf-8 but use traditional ascii markup in the bib file so `{\"o}` etc rather than using the letter directly, then the bib file is independent of the encoding used in the document, and can be used unchanged with documents with different encodings.