# References without accents

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm having troubles with BibTeX since the bibliography is eating all kind of (mostly Spanish) accents after compilation.

I'm using the [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package and `\bibliographystyle{utphys}`

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Have you consulted the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without seeing some of your code it is a little hard to see what is going on and to hep. Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}` so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved; I just added

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

and now it works.

Comment: Your answer doesn't fully solve all BibTeX-related issues that arise when words in an `author` or `title` field contain accented characters. I've closed your posting for now as a duplicate of an earlier posting. If you believe that your posting is *not* a duplicate, feel free to edit it -- preferably by providing an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) that generates the problem behavior you need to solve -- ask ask that the posting be re-opened