# What input encoding do I have to choose if I have an 'ɛ' in a reference title?

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings

I'm trying to cite [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/143888) in my assignment using bibtex. It has an 'ɛ' in the title and this does not get represented correctly in my pdf. Umlauts, which I also have, are not a problem.

So far I've tried

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

and

`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

but `pdflatex` asks for an interpretation in both cases.

I'm using jabref to manage my .bib file and there the ɛ is encoded as É^Û when I open it with `nano`.

Is there a way to solve this without using the method described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%C3%A4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography)? It works, but I would not want to have an expression like `{$\varepsilon$}` in jabref.

`locale` returns:

```
    LANG=
    LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
    LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
    LC_TIME="POSIX"
    LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
    LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
    LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
    LC_PAPER="POSIX"
    LC_NAME="POSIX"
    LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
    LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
    LC_ALL=
```

Correction:

The umlauts only work with `utf8` encoding.

Comment: It is hard to answer as the character in the question is a latin letter   U+025b LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E, but you  suggest that `\varepsilon` would work, but that is Greek, even though it may looks superficially similar.  What character do you actually need (and should it be in math or text)

Comment: Oh, they looked somewhat different to me, I just thought that they were the same, but I need the letter in the title of the paper, i.e. the LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E. How would I represent that using the latex encoding? And also it should be text, I guess, although I can't really tell from looking at it...

Comment: I have never seen that character used anywhere, ever:-) It is not in any of the standard tex encodings as far as I know, so if you are using pdftex I guess you will have to fake it with `$\varepsilon$` I'll add an answer showing how to get that output from the utf8 input

Comment: Wow really :-)? Well the paper is rather old, maybe they used it back then...ok thanks!

Comment: While that paper you cite is using a latin open e, I think that is simply a poor html encoding in that site, wikipedia suggests that the correct name is an epsilon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_Aurigae

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Just in case I encounter a similar situation in the future: is there a webpage or something where I can find out, what exact letter or symbol I'm looking at and how it is encoded in unicode? I will try your solution in the evening and the accept your answer, if I get it to work...

Comment: The canonical one is this http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ but actually I used this https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html (as it's my file:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using UTF-8 text input and rather basic math approximations we get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{025B}{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03F5}{\ensuremath{\epsilon}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B5}{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}

\begin{document}

latin open e U+025b [ɛ]  

lunate epsilon U+03f5 [ϵ] 

epsilon U+03b5 [ε]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the right packages, in this case `textalpha`; note that `ε` is U+03B5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON. Since we're dealing with the name of a star, the Greek letter is to be used. I also fixed the BibTeX entry for the paper, which had a few errors.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{1937ApJ....86..570K,
   author = {Kuiper, G. P. and Struve, O. and Str{\"o}mgren, B.},
    title = {The Interpretation of ε {Aurigae}},
  journal = {Astrophysical Journal},
     year = 1937,
    month = dec,
   volume = 86,
    pages = {570},
      doi = {10.1086/143888},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1937ApJ....86..570K},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % optional
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textalpha}

\begin{document}

\cite{1937ApJ....86..570K}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]