# The local links don't work

Tags: hyperref

I have my Tesis in latex, I am beginner, and the doc have a lot of local file link.
The questions is some of them work and others not.
The file are .pdf, I test permission, and it is ok.
I am looking for that by internet and I don't found the solution.
It's ilogical because with the same parameters the most work and the link open a pdf and others not.
I am not what to do.
Sorry for my english.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % output font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2} % encabezados
\pagestyle{scrheadings} %encabezados
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\baselineskip} %encabezados
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amscd,amsfonts}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % para quitar el warning de biblatex
\usepackage{emptypage} % para que en páginas en blanco no hayan encabezados ni pies de página
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{Graficos}
\usepackage[colorlinks,backref,a4paper,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
```

An example the link

This one work

sabemos de

```
\href{Vanguardia/Pierre Vilar o el desencanto-19760511.pdf}
{Pierre Vilar o el desencanto}
```

And this not

```
\href{Vanguardia/Quinta campaña de excavaciones en la cueva de
L'abreda-19790703.pdf}{Quinta
campaña de excavaciones en la cueva de l'Abreda}
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming the PDF so it does not have spaces in the name (spaces in file or folder name is a pain in most systems)

Comment: Yes I do and other .pd with ñ work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, it's a good idea to stay away from spaces. However, the difference I can see between the links that you have posted are the special characters (ñ). I would try removing them, or using the correct syntax (there is an explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%C3%A4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography)). Specifically:

This doesn't have special characters and you say it works:

```
    \href{Vanguardia/Pierre Vilar o el desencanto-19760511.pdf}
{Pierre Vilar o el desencanto}
```

This *has* special characters and you say it doesn't work:

```
\href{Vanguardia/Quinta campaña de excavaciones en la cueva de
L'abreda-19790703.pdf}{Quinta
campaña de excavaciones en la cueva de l'Abreda}
```

so try something like this instead:

```
\href{Vanguardia/Quinta campana de excavaciones en la cueva de
L'abreda-19790703.pdf}{Quinta
campa{\~n}a de excavaciones en la cueva de l'Abreda}
```

Comment: The same, other work. I try change and put {\~n}a and don't worl.

Comment: And always said that the file doesn't exist but exist.

Comment: Let me show some examples
Descubiertos en
\href{Vanguardia/Tarragona_ Nuevos hallazgos arqueológicos de la época tardorromana-19790401.pdf}
don't work
Albert Manent en
\href{Vanguardia/Iglesia y Estado en la España de 1932-19780121.pdf}
{Iglesia y Estado en la España de 1932} nos hace
work

There are ñ and work.
I don't know what to do or what it's wrong