# Special character in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, accents, characters

I can't put special characters like "ö" or umlaut "ü" in a bib entry, in spite of following the suggestions e.g. at [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%C3%A4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography) and putting the ASCII code in curly braces, like so {\aa}. The error message is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.
```

I can add them without problem in the body of the document. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might consider using `biblatex` and `biber`: `biber` understands `utf8`.

Comment: The error seems to be a TeX error, not a BibTeX error.  What happens if you put an Umlaut directly in your TeX file?  If you get the same error, then try to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (and save your file in utf8 encoding).

Comment: Can you post a minimal example document, including a `.bib` entry? I've only had errors from things like `{\"a}` in `.bib` entries when using Biber - not when using BibTeX. On the other hand, `ä` works fine for me with Biber (but would not work for BibTeX).

Comment: hi, what was the problem ? did you solve it ?

Comment: I didn't solve it... I worked around it by spelling out "ö" as {\"o} and so on