# Problem with accents and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

In some paper, I need to quote a mathematician called López. So I used the command \'{o} in my .bib file, but when I compile with the style alpha, I get an accent \'{} on the 9 of the first year number. This gives L\'{9}2, instead of L\'{o}p92. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: It should be `L{\'o}pez` in the `.bib` file

Comment: Maybe, use `bibtex8`? Or more simply, type `López` and use `biber`?

Comment: Thank you very much egreg, it worked. I use texstudio, and there is some automatic command for accents written in what seems to be an unproper way. Thank you Bernard, do you think it is better to use biber in general?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864) Note that you can only use Biber (which is better for 8-bit/Unicode input when it comes to sorting) together with `biblatex` and not traditional `.bst` styles (do you even use `biblatex`? you have tagged this question with the `biblatex` tag, but your question doesn't mention it and `alpha.bst` is a BibTeX style). Since some of `biblatex`'s features are only available for Biber it is generally the proffered back-end there.

Comment: Biber (which *only* works with `biblatex`, not `natbib` or anyhing else) is undoubtedly the way of the future, but if you have plans to publish a paper, you should consider what style the journal or publisher uses and see if you need to use a particular `.bst`. If yes, then Biber may not be for you. ... However, in my opinion, nowadays you should consider writing your master `.bib` file in UTF-8 and use Biber to export it to a traditional BibTeX-compliant `.bib` file when you need to use BibTeX. You get a clean main `.bib` fille, and it is easy to go Biber to BibTeX, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much moewe and jon for these very interesting explanations!