# Help for solving errors in bibliography: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, errors

I have been typing and copying text into my bibliography in LaTeX (using TeXmaker).. However, I keep getting two errors that I don't know how to fix.

The first error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.214 Lagunas-Bernabe, S., Cuaron-Ibargü
                                        engoytia, J., Montano-Hirose, J....
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
```

I have removed all weird letters and semicolons but it keeps on appearing. 
This is what it is being mad about:

```
@Article{Hofsaess2001, % here is the line where it finds the error
author = {Frederick R. Hofsaess},
title = {Time of antibody absorption in neonatal foals},
journal = {Journal of Equine Veterinary Science},
year = {2001},
volume = {21},
number = {4},
pages = {158-159}
}
```

What do I do?

The second error:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.
See the natbib package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.239 ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
Check the bibliography entries for non-compliant syntax,
or select author-year BibTeX style, e.g. plainnat
```

Here is where it says there is a problem:

```
@Article{Jang2013,
author = {Y. D. Jang and K. W. Kang and L. G. Piao and T. S. Jeong and E. Auclair and S. Jonvel and R. DInca and Y. Y. Kim}, 
title = {Effects of live yeast supplementation to gestation and lactation diets on reproductive performance, immunological parameters and milk composition in sows},
journal = {Livestock Science},
year = {2013}, % here is the line where it finds the error
volume = {152},
pages = {167-173}
}
```

I have tried to remove the parts that it said it had problems with, but the errors keep appearing..

Do anyone have a solution?

My bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{tex/litterature2}
```

Comment: I solved the first problem :)

Comment: Try retyping the line.

Comment: Thank you. I have added it below. Not sure if that was what you meant..
I have tried to retype, delete copy everything to new document, but the error remains..

Comment: [How do i provide a small compilable document?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: `bibtex` doesn't deal well with pre-accented letters.  the complaint you show first is about the `ü`.  change that to `\"u` in your `.bib` file (as well as fixing all other pre-accented letters) and rerun bibtex.  your `.bbl` file needs to be updated before you run latex again.

Comment: Regarding the first error: Did you see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: Regarding the second error: Be sure to specify the option `authoryear` when loading the `natbib` package. Also, delete all auxilliary files (especially those with extension .bbl and .aux) and do a full recompile (latex-bibtex-latex-latex).