# How to add a Ø to my bibliography from Jabref?

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

So I added the character for his name in Jabref just fine but when I typeset my document, the bibliography just completely omits the letter. His name is Østby and the bibliography just says "stby".

Thank you!

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: Do you compile the bibliography with `biber` or `bibtex`?

Comment: Assuming you use pdfLaTeX to compile the program, you should add, at a mininum, both `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your preamble. Furthermore, in the bib file, input the name as `{\O}stby` rather than as `Østby`. See [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) for more information on how to write "accented characters" in a bib file.

Comment: @Mico Any reasonable thing we can do here?

Comment: @Johannes_B - I went ahead and marked the posting as a duplicate.