# Citations in BibTeX format all at once

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am converting my word document to LaTeX document and now I have stopped at a point where I have to list all the citations to bibliography. I have refrences in APA format in word document. One option is that I individually copy citation from Google Scholar to LaTeX, but I am sure that there should be a shorter way of doing this, where I can get the BibTeX for all the citations **all at once**.

Thanks

I think I was not clear enough and therefore, I am reformatting my question below:

I have 50 references and I would like to have them in .bib format. Is there a easy way (like a website or tool) which can provided the .bib formatted references? OR do I have to get it from **Google scholar**, one by one?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334934/how-do-i-convert-a-word-files-references-to-bib-format

Comment: no.. no.. no.. This is not I am asking.

Comment: What's wrong with https://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/? Do you want a tool that not only reads the bibliography and converts the entries there to `.bib`, but also gets the full entry from Google Scholar?

Comment: @moewe: yes, that's what I need :)