# Converting MS word citations directly to LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, formatting, msword

I have more than 200 references formatted in MS Word, as given below:

> Farooqui, A., A. Khan, and S.U. Kazmi, *Investigation of a community
>   outbreak of typhoid fever associated with drinking water*. BMC Public
>   Health, 2009. 9(1): p. 1.

I want to copy all these refereces directly to LaTeX file. Is there anyway to do this easily?

Comment: Could you tell how did you produce those references (MS biblio, zotero or other tools, manually ...)?

Comment: @hkh actually i am helping a friend in coverting his MS Word thesis to LaTex. and he had written all these references manually.

Comment: please see this [How do I convert a Word file's references to .bib format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334934/how-do-i-convert-a-word-files-references-to-bib-format)

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is simply start each reference with a `\bibitem`  and enclose all in the `thebibliography`` environment, without using bibtex nor biblatex at all. But this is bread for today, and hunger for tomorrow, if you will need change the format in some way. The hard solution is make the bib file, but once made you can change the references format as many times as you want... without pain.

Comment: @Fran I would like to go with first solution. I am not an expert in LaTeX. Can you please write a small tempelate for what you are saying. I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem Just follow the "[basic approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604)" of the link.

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!