# Manually input bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm currently using Overleaf to write my dissertation and I'm trying to upload my bibliography.  I'm new to Overleaf/LaTeX, so I was unaware that I would need to code my in-text citations so that they would sync with the bibliography citations.  I have about 300 pages of work and I REALLY don't want to go back and change ALL of the in-text citations, but without this coding my bibliography at the end is basically blank.  Is there any way that I can manually input a bibliography at the end--so basically it's just more text at the end that isn't synced with the in-text citations?  I know it's not ideal, so other options are greatly appreciated as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: your question is very unclear, how have you marked up your citations and your bibliography?  you have tagged the question bibtex and biblatex, and using either of those the bibliography is generated automatically. You can obviously just write the bibliography by hand as a list at the end (although not usually recommened) it works

Comment: Please tell us what the in-text citation call-outs look like at present -- and how they should look like in the finished product. You further mention that you have a bibliography: How is it organized at present? Does the present formatting satisfy the university's formal requirement for bibliographies?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry it's unclear! I used those tags because they were programs that I tried before and I didn't know if there was a way to use those programs and also somehow unsync the entries from the in-text citations OR not use them and manually input my bibliography entries.  Hope that clears it up!

Comment: @Mico My in-text citations at the moment are in the (Author Date) format but they're not coded in any special way I just wrote them out.  And yes, I've been working on my bibliography word document for like 4 years so it is in the university's style and it's very organized, it's just not something I can simply copy and paste into overleaf.  Does that make sense? Sorry I'm new to all of this so please let me know what I need to clarify!

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, (a) the citation call-outs are all hard-coded, (b) the bibliographic entries are all hard-coded as well and reside in an external file (called, say, `mybib.tex`, located in the same directory as the main tex file), and (c) you're not willing and/or able to change this setup. If this understanding is correct, all you need to do -- or, frankly, can do -- is write `\section*{References}` (or maybe `\chapter*{References}`) in the main tex file, followed by `\input mybib`.

Answer (score 3):

Given the comments, I take it that your problem is the following:

1. You have a thesis written in LaTeX
2. You have a manually created and formatted bibliography in Word.
3. Your citation callouts are simply written into your source document without using any bibliography package.

Given this situation you have two main options, the choice of which depends on your time constraints, and how much forward compatibility you need with respect to your bibliography. (i.e., will you need it again, or will it exist only for your thesis?)

### Option 1: Create a `.bib` file

If you have time, and you envision needing the bibliography for future documents, then it would be well worth the time to create a proper `.bib` file out of your Word document.  There are online tools to help ease this process. It's by no means completely automatic, so you will likely need to do some manual cleanup of the resulting file, but it certainly will save you from entering everything manually.

- [How do I convert a Word file's references to .bib format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334934/2693)

Once you've created this file you will need to find a bibliography style that matches your university requirements. I would recommend starting with one of the `biblatex` styles and working from there, since they are generally easier to modify, especially when there are odd requirements. Once you have decided this, you have two options with your in text citations:

1. Convert all your hard coded in text citation callouts to proper `\cite{...}` commands for the relevant bibliography package, and create your bibliography in an automated way.
2. Don't fix any of your hard coded citation callouts, and simply use `\nocite{*}` to include your entire `.bib` file as the bibliography.

So schematically your thesis would then look like the following:

```
\documentclass{book} % or whatever class you are using
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex} % an easily modifiable author-year style
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib} % name of your bibliography file
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
This is some research that I read (Dewey, Cheetham and Howe, 2021). As Smith (1993) showed. 
% add all of the contents of the .bib file to the bibliography without callouts
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Your `.bib` file should obviously contain only those references that you have actually cited in the thesis in your manually written callouts. So in this example, the `.bib` file would contain only the entries for `Smith1993` and `DeweyCheethamHowe2021`.

### Option 2: Create a totally manual bibliography

The second option is to simply create a completely hard coded bibliography. To do this you could use `pandoc` to convert your Word bibliography into a `.tex` file, and then using the `hanging` package, input the resultant `.tex` file in the `hangparas` environment (since bibliographies typically have a hanging indent). This is the really quick and dirty solution, and would work if you didn't really care about the long term future of your bibliography, or you are so short on time, you can't implement Option 1.  Unfortunately I don't think you can run `pandoc` on Overleaf, so this solution would require a proper TeX distribution on your computer plus `pandoc`. As a concrete example, here is a small LaTeX document I created simply by using the following `pandoc` command:

```
pandoc wordbib.docx -o wordbib.tex
```

and then adding the appropriate preamble code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}
\section{References}
\begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}
Abels, Klaus (2002) `Successive cyclicity, anti-locality and adposition
stranding.' PhD dissertation University of Connecticut.

Hornstein, Norbert \& Amy Weinberg (1981) `Case theory and preposition
stranding.' \emph{Linguistic Inquiry} 12, 55--91.

Kampen, Jacqueline van (1996) `PF/LF convergence in acquisition.' In K.
Kusumoto (ed.) \emph{Proceedings of the North East Linguistic Society}
(NELS) 26, 149 - 163. University of Mass., Amherst: GLSA.

\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

In your use case, you would create this file, add the `hanging` package to your preamble, wrap the converted references in the `hangparas` environment and then use `\input{wordbib}` in your main document after an appropriate chapter/section heading.

Comment: Thank you! I would be totally willing to do part 2 of the first option, but I'm wondering where in my code should I put \nocite{*} ?  Before each citation in the bibliography?

Comment: @SCasciato I've given a schematic example of how to do this.