# Journal of Finance Template German '*.bst'

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, jabref, german

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis and I am using LyX as my standard writing program (because I am not familiar with LaTeX at all).

For my bibliographystyle I use JabRef and the citation style needs to be *Journal of Finance*.

Now, I found this `.bst` file for the *Journal of Finance* style online (http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/) which is actually really good. But the problem is, that I need it in German. There must be an "und" instead of "and" and all the umlauts don't work as well. Basically I need everything in German.

Do you know a website with a German `.bst` file? Or can I change something in the settings in LyX or JabRef and everything would be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you want to use a `.bst` file you are not using `biblatex` at all, you are using BibTeX. So I have removed the tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just to double-check, you've set the language to German in LyX in Document > Settings > Language, right?

Comment: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.bst has some string definitions that would have to be translated into German. To do that copy the file, rename it to `jf-german.bst` and translate the terms in quotation marks in the functions called `FUNCTION {bbl.<...>}` (e.g. `"and"` in `FUNCTION {bbl.and}`). Then use `jf-german` in your document instead of `jf`. It's a bit too late for me to write up a proper answer, but maybe that can help you already. I can write up something tomorrow if you haven't gotten a good answer until then.

Comment: `ü`, `ö`, `ä` should more or less work if the encoding settings of your `.tex` and `.bib` file match (best is to have both in UTF-8). Otherwise you can use `{\"o}` for `ö`, `{\"a}` for `ä` etc in the `.bib` file (and only in the `.bib` file, you should use slightly different code in the actual document). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864

Comment: One last thing: You don't use JabRef for your bibliography *style* (`\bibliographystyle`). You use JabRef to write your `.bib` database that contains the bibliography entries you can cite. JabRef does not determine the style of your bibliography or citation output in the actual document. That is done by the `.bst` file - the BibTeX style file.

Comment: Do check out the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) for advice on how to input "accented" characters, including characters with umlauts, in a .bib file.

Comment: Many are confused. You have to learn LaTeX first to properly use LyX.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're working with the file `jf.bst` that's available online at http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jf/jf.bst, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of `jf.bst` and call the copy, say, `jfgerman.bst`. (Of course, you're free to come up with a different name.)
- Open the file `jfgerman.bst` in a plain-text editor. (I'm afraid I have no idea if `lyx` can do this.)
- In `jfgerman.bst`, locate the group of functions called `bbl.and`, `bbl.editors`, `bbl.editor`, `bbl.edby`, etc. Replace the English-language arguments with their German-language counterparts. I know that "and" should become "und". I trust you'll figure out what to do about "eds.", "ed.", "edited by", etc.
- Save the file `jfgerman.bst` in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- In your main tex file, change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `jf` to `jfgerman` and perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more) to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: If someone wants to post a complementary answer that's more lyx-oriented, please feel free to do so.

Comment: I don't think a separate answer is needed. As for whether LyX can edit bst files, no it does not edit plain-text files. For your last point, the user just needs to click on the BibTeX inset and select jfgerman instead of jf.

Comment: @scottkosty - Many thanks for providing these pointers.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! You probably realised that I have no clue with LyX and JabRef, I am sorry!
So there is no easier way than to change everything? I am just worried that I forget to change something...
Two more questions:
1. Can I use google Scholar to cite? I copy the BibTex-Code and then I put it in JabRef or is that a bad citation?
2. This one is connected to the first one. If I change something in the BibTex code, which is in JabRef (for example use of capital and small initial letters) it changes in JabRef but the References in LyX don't change the initial letters?

Comment: Google scholar is not really a good qualitative source. Whenever possible you should use the DOI, an arxiv identifier or any other provided identifier to have a high quality bibtex source. @mico Not really. You always have the source view for every bibtex/biblatex entry and JabRef's native file format is bib, so there is nothing really hidden from the user. However, it also provides ways to cleanup things or to fill out missing info. If you think there's room for improvement feel free to open an issue ;)

Comment: @ChristophS - My sincere apologies if I overstated things. I actually haven't worked with JabRef for several years. St the time, I concluded that it didn't do some of the things I wanted to get done, while performing other tasks that weren't relevant to my workflow. (Believe it or not, I actually *like* to see the underlying BibTeX code...) I will readily admit that this experience may not be of much relevance for the current version of JabRef. I'll also delete my earlier comment.

Comment: I changed the .bst file and I guess in the References at the end of the Document everything is okay (the authors are connected with an "und") but I still got issues in the text itself. The Authors are still linked with "and" so it's in the text: [Ritz and Thom (2011)] and at the End of the file: [Ritz, Adrian, und Norbert Thom, 2011, Talent Management: Talente identifizieren, Kompetenzen
entwickeln, Leistungsträger erhalten, zweite Auflage (Gabler, Wiesbaden). ]

Comment: Do I need to change the Standard-BibTex-Style in the settings?

Comment: Don't forget that one must rerun LaTeX *twice* after modifying a bst file and running BibTeX, in order to fully propagate all changes. Your observation, "...in the text: [Ritz and Thom (2011)]...", sure makes it sound like you reran LaTeX only once, not twice.