# Special character \~{a} (ã) using bibtex not displaying

Tags: bibtex, accents, characters

I am writing a document and I want to include a reference of a person called Catalão. I put the line related to the author in the entry on bibtex as:

author = {P. S. Catal\~{a}o}

However, when I compile my document on latex, I get the following outcome:
[image]

How can correctly insert the character ã on bibtex?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864: `author = {P. S. Catal{\~a}o}` (see also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibaccent)

Comment: thank you @moewe, apparently I did not search thoroughly and properly, my apologies. The answer you indicated solved my issue. Should I delete my question?

Comment: No, there is no need to delete the question, but you can agree with the duplicate vote. Duplicate answers remain searchable and can help others find the other question more easily.