# Ø is not understood in text, but only in my bib-file, and vice versa

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings

Sorry for my confusing title. :) I'm a newbie, so please bear with me.

I use

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but in order to write Ø, I have to write `\O{}` in the text. However in my bib-file, there are lots of Øs and Ås which are treated correctly.

I've tried switching to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

instead of `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. 
Now the Øs and Ås in the text work well (without me having to write `\O{}`), but now the bib-file gives me many errors (it can't read Æ Ø). This is so confusing.

I've read that I should switch to biblatex, but the document is so big and we need a certain style etc., so I don't think we can do that.

I use Winedt.
Thanks!

Comment: presumably your bib files are stored in latin1 (iso-8859-1) and your main text file is stored in UTF-8, the simplest thing is to use your editor to save all the files in UTF-8.

Comment: This suggests that your `.tex` file and your `.bib` file use different file encodings. Make sure that both use the same encoding (I would prefer UTF-8). Though it should be noted that BibTeX does not officially support non-ASCII characters. In practice you will not always notice this, since non-ASCII chars are usually passed through as they are, but for sorting and label generation this could be an issue. So for BibTeX the official advice is still to use macros to write non-ASCII chars (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/).

Comment: The other alternative is `biblatex`/Biber (you mentioned it yourself, and apparently this is not feasible for this project, but maybe for future work, though one has to keep in mind that publishers probably won't accept `biblatex` submissions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864).

Comment: Okay, thanks! Very much appreciated! How do I switch the bib file from latin to UTF-8? Still a newbie.. :)

Comment: Did you see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)? If you can't figure out how to perform the change in file input encodings, you could perform a global change, in the bib file, of all instances of `Ø` for `{\O}`, of `Å` for `\Aa`, etc. Thereafter, BibTeX will perform just fine.

Comment: Sorry, no. I Guess moewe is correct in that the encodings are different. I have no idea how to change it, and frankly, I just found a practical solution (I really didnt need Ø very much).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.