# Revtex 4.2 Bibliography not working

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, revtex

My tex file is running without any issue. But when I try to incorporate bibliography, the references are not getting generated. I've added the citation to bib file using JabRef and also defined the citation style correctly. I'm using revtex 4.2 for typing my article.

[Bib log generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr54E.jpg)
[image: Tex log generated]

Comment: BibTeX is not very fond of file names with whitespace. Try to drop all spaces in file names. What exactly did you write as argument to `\bibliography` in your document?

Comment: I should say that `Bu\ifmmode \check{z}\else \v{z}\fi{}ek` looks *extremely* suspicious (if not to say outright wrong). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864 for hints on writing accented characters in `.bib` files.

Comment: \bibliography{test}  @moewe

Comment: I just copied the downloaded the bibtex file from aps site and made test.bib file using JabRef. I haven't changed the font. I'll try changing the font now and let you know. @moewe

Comment: Changing the author name didn't help. Can you check this log file also? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr54E.jpg  @moewe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do make sure that your tex file doesn't include any whitespace characters in the file name.

If the name of the tex file is `1st draft updated.tex`, LaTeX creates an associated aux file named `1st draft updated.aux`. Among the pieces of information written to the aux file are the name(s) of the bib file(s), the bibliography style that's supposed to be employed, and the arguments of `\cite`-like instructions. BibTeX peruses the aux file, not the tex file, in order to find out what it's supposed to do. As you've (re)discovered, BibTeX cannot handle whitespace characters in file names.

Summing up: The issue you've encountered is *not* related to either the `revtex4-2` document class or the `apsrev4-2` bibliography style. To "fix" the problem, simply change the name of the tex file from `1st draft updated.tex` to `1stdraftupdated.tex` (or some other name that doesn't contain space characters) and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

[image]

The name of the file that the contains the following code is `test.tex` -- note the absence of whitespace.

```
%%% test.tex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ttt.bib}
@article{hillery1999,
  title    = {Quantum secret sharing},
  author   = {Hillery, Mark and Bu{\v z}ek, Vladim{\'i}r and Berthiaume, Andr{\'e}},
  journal  = {Phys.\ Rev.~A},
  volume   = {59},
  issue    = {3},
  pages    = {1829--1834},
  numpages = {0},
  year     = {1999},
  month    = {Mar},
  publisher= {American Physical Society},
  doi      = {10.1103/PhysRevA.59.1829},
  url      = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.59.1829}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
\frenchspacing % optional
\begin{document}
\cite{hillery1999}
\bibliography{ttt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is filecontents package used for creating the .bib file directly from the tex file? @Mico

Comment: Thanks. Its working correctly. @Mico

Comment: @Govind - Indeed, the `fileconents` environment lets you write to external files from within a LaTeX document.