# Author name in bibliography contains special letters

Tags: bibliographies, input-encodings

I have a reference for article where author name contains several specific characters. Do I need a specific package for this case:
Here is the reference:

```
@article{matouvsek1998thel2,
  title={On the {$L_2$}-discrepancy for anchored boxes},
  author={Matou{\v{s}}ek, Ji{\v{r}}{\i}́},
  journal={Journal of Complexity},
  volume={14},
  number={4},
  pages={527--556},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't need anything special. However it looks like you have a rather weird character near the `}` (a U+0301 Combining Acute Accent in `}́}`) of the `author` field, so you are probably getting errors because of that.

Comment: Since the name is *Jiří Matoušek* you want `Matou{\v{s}}ek, Ji{\v{r}}{\'i}` (or `Matou{\v{s}}ek, Ji{\v{r}}{\'{\i}}`) for BibTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864). If you are using `biblatex` with Biber you can just say `Matoušek, Jiří`. The problem in the example is the trailing acute accent in `{\i}́`. (You shouldn't need special packages, but you will need a font and will probably want a font encoding that support the letters properly.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Let's assume that you use the Computer Modern font family and pdfLaTeX to compile your document. In that case, you do not need to load any packages to typeset the three accented characters in the `author` field of your bibliographic entry -- r-with v-check, s-with-v-check, and dotless-i. (Aside: did you mean to write `{\'i}`, i.e., i-with-sharp-accent, instead of dotless-i?) However, for some other accented characters, such as ogonek-a or ogonek-k, you will need to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.

If you have the option to employ either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you won't have to load any special packages.

Comment: I wrote it as Ji{\v r \' i} but there is space between the last 2 letters of Jiří . it is shown reference as Jiř í. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Adam -- Is there a reason for leaving a space between `\'` and `i`? Anyway, I don't think you can go wrong by writing the author field as follows: `author = "Matou{\v s}ek, Ji{\v r}{\'i}"`.

Comment: @Adam, you need to write "accented letters" in BibTeX as '{\accent letter}'. In your case, "Matou{\v s}ek, Ji{\v r}{\' \i}" (yes, '\i' if you don't want an 'i' with dot and accent).