# pdflatex not printing hyphen in reference generated with bibtex, unless protected with brackets

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I have an entry in a .bib file consisting of:

```latex
author = {Garrido-Jurado, S. and Mu\~{n}oz-Salinas, R. and Madrid-Cuevas, F.J. and Mar\'{i}n-Jim\'{e}nez, M.J.},
```

and run

```
pdflatex file.tex
bibtex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

the result is

[image]:

(notice there is no hyphen in between 'Muñoz' and 'Salinas') --

S. Garrido-Jurado, R. Muñoz Salinas, F. Madrid-Cuevas,and M. Marı́n-Jiménez

+++
Now, if I add a bracket around the hyphen, and follow all of the other steps, success:

```latex
author = {Garrido-Jurado, S. and Mu\~{n}oz{-}Salinas, R. and Madrid-Cuevas, F.J. and Mar\'{i}n-Jim\'{e}nez, M.J.},
```

[image]

or

S. Garrido-Jurado, R. Muñoz-Salinas, F. Madrid-Cuevas,and M. Marı́n-Jiménez

The question is: why?  The hyphen was printed correctly for Marı́n-Jiménez, why was Muñoz-Salinas such an issue?

(I will also mention I am using the current version of IEEEtran.bst .)

Comment: This is odd. The exact behaviour here depends on the bibliography style you are using. Please tell us which bibliography package you are using and which style (`\bibliographystyle`). This is best done in a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: BibTeX needs additional braces around the entire non-ASCII character, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864. `author = {Garrido-Jurado, S. and Mu{\~n}oz-Salinas, R. and Madrid-Cuevas, F. J. and Mar{\'i}n-Jim{\'e}nez, M. J.},` works for me.

Comment: Thanks!  I was working on the MWE and was able to test that this is the case.  I have many authors with diacritical marks in their names, so this will come in handy.