# Citation problem

Tags: citing, apacite

Why this citation does not work?

```
@article{babecky2014banking,
  title={Banking, debt, and currency crises in developed countries: Stylized facts and early warning indicators},
  author={Babeck{\`y}, Jan and Havr{\'a}nek, Tom{\'a}{\v{s}} and Mat{\v{e}}j{\uu}, Jakub and Rusn{\'a}k, Marek and {\v{S}}m{\'\i}dkov{\'a}, Kate{\v{r}}ina and Va{\v{s}}{\'\i}{\v{c}}ek, Bo{\v{r}}ek},
  journal={Journal of Financial Stability},
  volume={15},
  pages={1--17},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

After compiling I get this error:

[image]

Comment: As it says, where is `\uu` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean \u{u} instead of \uu?

```
@article{babecky2014banking,
  title={Banking, debt, and currency crises in developed countries: Stylized facts and early warning indicators},
  author={Babeck{\`y}, Jan and Havr{\'a}nek, Tom{\'a}{\v{s}} and Mat{\v{e}}j{\u{u}}, Jakub and Rusn{\'a}k, Marek and {\v{S}}m{\'\i}dkov{\'a}, Kate{\v{r}}ina and Va{\v{s}}{\'\i}{\v{c}}ek, Bo{\v{r}}ek},
  journal={Journal of Financial Stability},
  volume={15},
  pages={1--17},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: `{\r u}` would be better than `{\u u}`.

Answer (score 3):

This bibliographic entry surely merits using "native" accented characters instead of the cumbersome alternative. Compile with either `natbib`/BibTeX or `biblatex`/biber.

If, however, you can't employ

```
author = "Jan Babecký and Tomáš Havránek and Jakub Matějů 
          and Marek Rusnák and Kateřina Šmídková 
          and Bořek Vašíček",
```

you should set the `author` field as follows:

```
author = "Jan Babeck{\'y} and Tom{\'a}{\v s} Havr{\'a}nek and Jakub Mat{\v e}j{\r u} 
          and Marek Rusn{\'a}k and Kate{\v r}ina {\v S}m{\'i}dkov{\'a} 
          and Bo{\v r}ek Va{\v s}{\'i}{\v c}ek",
```

See [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) for more information on how to enter 'accented' characters in a bib file. Shameless self-citation alert! :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
%% Source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572308914000606
@article{babecky-etal:2014,
author = "Jan Babecký and Tomáš Havránek and Jakub Matějů and Marek Rusnák 
          and Kateřina Šmídková and Bořek Vašíček",
title  = "Banking, debt, and currency crises in developed countries: Stylized 
          facts and early warning indicators",
journal= "Journal of Financial Stability",
volume = "15",
pages  = "1--17",
year   = "2014",
issn   = "1572-3089",
doi    = "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfs.2014.07.001",
url    = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572308914000606",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % use a font family with required "accented" characters
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\citet{babecky-etal:2014}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two downvotes in one day, in short succession no less. That's a new one. I looks like I seriously annoyed somebody! No idea why, so it's not going to affect my future behavior...

Answer (score 1):

In the original article you have Jakub Matějů, see, e.g., https://econpapers.repec.org/paper/ecbecbwps/20121485.htm, so it should be
`and Mat{\v{e}}j{\r{u}}, Jakub`