# Decrease the distance between these two formulas

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I decrease the distance between the following two formulas?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\noindent\\
Ta có: $$ \begin{array}{c}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \cap A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \cap A \Leftrightarrow
\text{$
    \begin{cases}
    y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\
    y- \alpha \in A
    \end{cases}$}\Leftrightarrow \text{$
    \begin{cases}
    y \in E \\
    y \in \alpha+A
    \end{cases}$}
\end{array}
$$
$$ \begin{array}{c}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \setminus A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \setminus A \Leftrightarrow
\text{$
    \begin{cases}
    y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\
    y- \alpha \notin A
    \end{cases}$}\Leftrightarrow \text{$
    \begin{cases}
    y \in E \\
    y \notin \alpha+A
    \end{cases}$}
\end{array}
$$
Ta chứng minh $x+A$, $xA$ là $L$-đo được.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: sorry, my editor cannot deal with your accented characters, so I had to drop them. Then

1. You should not put a `cases` environment in `\text{$...$}`, but you do not need `cases` here anyway. The `case` environment expects two columns, which is why it introduces the extra space here.
2. Please do not use `$$...$$`, but `\[...\]` instead.
3. You can use an array here.
4. I had a little help from David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Ta co: \begin{gather*}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \cap A]
 \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \cap A \Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
    y- \alpha \in A 
    \end{array}\right. \Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    y \in E \\ 
    y \in \alpha+A
    \end{array}\right.
\\
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \setminus A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \setminus A \Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} 
    y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
    y- \alpha \notin A 
    \end{array}\right.\Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} 
    y \in E \\ 
    y \notin \alpha+A
    \end{array}\right.
\end{gather*}
Ta chung minh $x+A$, $xA$ la $L$-do duoc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

One may also use `aligned`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Ta co: 
\[\begin{aligned}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \cap A]
 \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \cap A \Leftrightarrow
    &\left\{\begin{aligned}
    &y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
    &y- \alpha \in A 
    \end{aligned}\right. \Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
    &y \in E \\ 
    &y \in \alpha+A
    \end{aligned}\right.
\\
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \setminus A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \setminus A \Leftrightarrow
    &\left\{\begin{aligned} 
    &y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
    &y- \alpha \notin A 
    \end{aligned}\right.\Leftrightarrow
    \left\{\begin{aligned} 
    &y \in E \\ 
    &y \notin \alpha+A
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{aligned}   
\]
Ta chung minh $x+A$, $xA$ la $L$-do duoc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: too adjacent display math :(  (`gather` is designed for that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Better now? (I just can't remember `gather`, for some reason it always becomes `\begin{gopher}` and then LaTeX gives me an error.)

Comment: if I was being picky I'd say that the "One may also use" could say "The above is wrong but you could instead use" but I'm not picky so +1 :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, my editor had the old version in the buffer. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: because tex  just doesn't do anything sensible if display math is at start of a paragraph or immediately following another display math (I think I have an answer giving gory details somewhere, I'll see if I can find)

Comment: No, I got it,. I just happened to copy the wrong version. Now there is a `gopher` environment. Thanks!

Comment: What editor? [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) on Linux? It (auto detect) sometimes thinks it is [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) when it is clearly not (e.g. for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) sequence C3 96 for "Ö" - e.g. in [LÖVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6ve_(game_engine))).

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, I have an ancient one. But if you look at [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545782/fun-titles-by-splitting-in-letters-or-words/545786#comment1378880_545784) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545157/194703) then you may understand why some do not want to use these accented characters anyway. I know and acknowledge that I am in a minority, but I am not ready to give up the convenience of my ancient editor for for a somewhat shaky convenience of adding all these accented characters.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it works as desired! Just use the `setspace` package and control the `setstretch` option. And try to use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{.75}

\begin{document}
\noindent\\
Ta có: $$ \begin{array}{c}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \cap A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha+E) \cap A \Leftrightarrow
\text{$
\begin{cases} 
y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
y- \alpha \in A 
\end{cases}$}\Leftrightarrow \text{$
\begin{cases} 
y \in E \\ 
y \in \alpha+A
\end{cases}$}
\end{array}
$$
$$ \begin{array}{c}
\forall y \in \alpha + [(-\alpha+E) \setminus A] \Leftrightarrow y- \alpha \in (-\alpha +E) \setminus A \Leftrightarrow
\text{$
\begin{cases} 
y-\alpha \in -\alpha +E \\ 
y- \alpha \notin A 
\end{cases}$}\Leftrightarrow \text{$
\begin{cases} 
y \in E \\ 
y \notin \alpha+A
\end{cases}$}
\end{array}
$$
Ta chứng minh $x+A$, $xA$ là $L$-đo được.
\end{document}
```

Comment: never have `\noindent\\ ` and never have adjacent display math, a multi-line display such as `gather` should be used.