# Order of entries in BibTeX bibliography with umlaut ä

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use BibTeX and some authors name begins with an umlaut `Ä` (written `{\"A}` in LaTeX).
Somewhere on this site I read that BibTex treats `Ä` the same way as `A`.
Now I wonder because BibTeX orders `An` before `Äl`. This is strange, because
if one interprets `Ä` as `A` or even as `Ae`, in both cases `Äl` should be before `An`.
What is happening here? It seems like BibTex simply orders `Ä` after `A`, which is in conflict with what I have seen so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "Somewhere on this [site] I read that BibTeX treats `Ä` the same way as `A`." Would you be able to find out *where* you read this? The reason I ask is this is because the claim is *false*. Indeed, *for sorting purposes*, BibTeX treats all accented characters as coming *after* `Z`. Hence, not only does BibTeX place `Äl` after `An`, it even places it after `Zy`. For more information on this subject, see [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try with `biblatex+biber`? Biber understands utf8.

Comment: @Mico: No, in my case `Äl` comes before `B`. The link you posted in your comment is exactly the reference I was thinking of. Here it says that `{\"o}` and `o` are equivalent.

Comment: @user148364 -- Please note: The main answer in the posting I provided a link to says that `{\"o}` and `o` are equivalent for BibTeX's sorting algorithm. It definitely does *not* say that `ö` and `o` (or, for that matter, `Ä` and `A`) are equivalent for BibTeX's sorting algorithm.

Comment: I thought the first sentence in my question made clear that I produced `Ä` always with `{\"A}`.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the claim I made in the earlier comment, that BibTeX sorts `Äl` not only after `An` but also after `Zy`, I've constructed the following minimalist example, which employs four "dummy" bibliographic entries with surnames `Äl`, `{\"A}l`, `An`, and `Zy`. Note that the `Äl` entry is sorted dead last, whereas the `{\"A}l` entry is placed first, as expected.

[image]

Again, for a lot more information on how one should enter accented letters in bibliographic entries processed by BibTeX, see [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{al,author="Äl",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{al2,author="{\"A}l",title="Thoughts",year=3002}
@misc{an,author="An",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{zy,author="Zy",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
% Or some other bib style that sorts entries alphabetically by authors' surnames

\begin{document}
\cite{zy,an,al,al2}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear enough. I always used `{\"A}` in my code and never  `Ä`. Still, in the end I get the ordering **An**, **Äl**, **Zy**.

Comment: @user148364 - Well, in the answer I provided, the `al2` entry (which uses `{\"A}l`) *is* placed before the `an` entry (which uses `An`). Please edit your posting to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Stating that you're experiencing a problem is *not enough* to permit coming up a firm diagnosis, let alone to permit suggesting a cure.