# ASCII encoding option in texshop

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I need my bib file to be ASCII encoded so that it works when Lyx invokes Bibtex for my bibliography and referencing. However within TeXShop on my mac I can't find the option to encode in ASCII. UTF-8 does not work. What do i need to do to have it encode in ASCII

Comment: I can't help with texshop but utf8 and ascii are the same thing in the ascii range so if you only write it using ascii, so `{\'e}` not the accented letter, it doesn't matter if it is saved as utf-8 or ascii as there is no difference.

Comment: It would be simpler to invoke `biber`, which understands utf8.

Comment: See also [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001) for more information on how to input "accented characters" in a bib file for processing with BibTeX.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting for ASCII but you must make sure you only type characters that are in the ASCII set; e.g., you can only type accented characters using macros (e.g., \'e instead of é directly) since accented characters are not part of the ASCII set. Please read the`Help->File Encoding and TeXShop` document for more information. Most single byte encodings and UTF-8 Unicode actual have ASCII as a subset.