# errors when trying to add bibliography to report

Tags: bibliographies

I have a paper I am writing and have to use a specific template from my university. I have been able to get it to a format closer to what I am used to but I am having trouble where I cannot add the bibliography, and get a number of errors. I have been searching online on how to fix it and am yet to find a way so I am hoping someone can shed some light on the issue here.

I have added a condensed version of my tex file below to show what I am doing. I have tried adding the bibliography normally as is shown and tried beginning (\begin{thebibliography}) and ending (\end{thebibliography}) style also with both giving errors. For the normal implementation shown below of just adding a .bib file, I get various errors like.

```
+Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "8E. \begin{thebibliography}{}
+Undefined control sequence. \bibitem{lee2019}
+Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

Can anyone help to fix this issue and add a bibliography. Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{jgraduate2012}

\usepackage{graphicx}
.
.
.
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{section1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You won't need to manually insert any `\begin{thebibliography}` or `\end{thebibliography}` with this setup. BibTeX automatically generates this environment in a temporary file you should normally not edit. Remove any such commands you may have manually added to your files.

Comment: The error message `Invalid UTF-8 byte "8E.` could be caused by a wrong file encoding in your `.bib` file (as shown your document expects UTF-8) or by using Unicode characters where BibTeX tries to apply certain string operations (cf. e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571189/35864). We would be able to say more if you could isolate the problematic `.bib` entry and share it with us.

Comment: Similar things apply for the other errors: You need to identify which entry causes the trouble. Note that the error messages shown in the question are not the complete error messages that LaTeX would produce on a normal run. Those messages look like they might have been parsed by your editor. It is definitely worth a try to look at the raw `.log` file for more hints. Sometimes editors hide important bits of the error message.

Comment: Only tangentially related (and it definitely will *not* solve the problem), but the correct syntax for `\bibliography{<bibliography file name>}` is to give `<bibliography file name>` *without* the `.bib` file extension. So *`\bibliography{reference.bib}` should be `\bibliography{reference}`. Some older systems will not find the file correctly if you erroneously include the `.bib` file extension in your call to `\bibliography`.

Comment: I though that it may have to do with encoding in single entries previously so I tried removing all entries in the .bib file and adding single entries one at a time and it still gives the same errors. I have also tried using bibliography command with and without the .bib extension without any change.

Comment: If you add or remove `.bib` entries to create an MWE delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` file and recompile with a full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle. Otherwise old data may remain in the temporary files and still cause troubles. (As I said, dropping the `.bib` file extension is not the solution to your problem, but it should still be done.)