# BibTex And Hyphenated First Names Combined With Language Typical Markings/Diacritics

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, hyphenation

In a reference, I want the first name to be printed in the following way:
[image]

I tried various variants:

```
@incollection{KariVolkov2021,
  author    = {Jarkko Kari and Mikhail V. Volkov},
  editor    = {Jean-Eric Pin},
  title     = {{\v{C}ern\'y's} conjecture and the road colouring problem},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Automata Theory, Volume I},
  pages     = {525--565},
  publisher = {European Mathematical Society Publishing House},
  year      = {2021},
}
```

This gives the intended behaviour with the hyphen. However, the stress mark is missing: [image]

So, it seems logical to add this mark:

```
@incollection{KariVolkov2021,
  author    = {Jarkko Kari and Mikhail V. Volkov},
  editor    = {Jean-\'{E}ric Pin},
  title     = {{\v{C}ern\'y's} conjecture and the road colouring problem},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Automata Theory, Volume I},
  pages     = {525--565},
  publisher = {European Mathematical Society Publishing House},
  year      = {2021},
}
```

However, this gives the following: [image]

So, as a last try I tried to put "{}" around the hyphen:

```
@incollection{KariVolkov2021,
  author    = {Jarkko Kari and Mikhail V. Volkov},
  editor    = {Jean{-}\'{E}ric Pin},
  title     = {{\v{C}ern\'y's} conjecture and the road colouring problem},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Automata Theory, Volume I},
  pages     = {525--565},
  publisher = {European Mathematical Society Publishing House},
  year      = {2021},
}
```

But this only results in: [image]

Any ideas how to get the corrent form?

Comment: bibtex wants accents marked as `{\'E}`

Comment: Oh, yes thank you! It works. Would you mind giving this as an answer (possibly with some explanation why the other variant is not working)?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bibtex has very limited support for non-ascii characters, It needs accented letters in the form `{\'E}` so the outer brace group keeps things as a single unit.