# I have a problem when I'm trying to cite a reference

Tags: bibliographies, citing

So im using **Overleaf**, and here is my project setup :

```
root
├── 1. Etat de l'art
    ├── 1. RS.tex
    ├── 2. CARS.tex
    ├── 3. IoT.tex
    └── etat_de_l'art.tex
├── 2. Conception
├── 3. Implementation
├── Figures
├── bibliographie.bib
└── pfe.tex
```

The pfe.tex is the main file that regroups all the subfiles. Here is the content of the pfe.tex

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}

\geometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\linespread{1.25}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

\author{}
\title{PFE}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{État de l'art}
\input{1. État de l'art/etat_de_l'art.tex}

\bibliographysytle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}
\end{document}
```

Now in the RS.tex Im trying to cite something for the bibliographie.bib file, but It's giving me and error saying that the citation can't be found.

Here is the content of RS.tex

```latex
\subsection{Définition des RSs}
De nos jours, l’avancement des performances des ordinateurs et des réseaux informatiques 
nous on permet d’exploiter encore plus le monde virtuel, et de numériser nos activités 
quotidiennes comme le shopping, la lecture des journaux \cite{lu_recommender_2012}.
```

And here is the bibliographie.bib file :

```
@article{lu_recommender_2012,
    series = {Recommender {Systems}},
    title = {Recommender systems},
    volume = {519},
    issn = {0370-1573},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157312000828},
    doi = {10.1016/j.physrep.2012.02.006},
    abstract = {The ongoing rapid expansion of the Internet greatly increases the necessity of effective recommender systems for filtering the abundant information. Extensive research for recommender systems is conducted by a broad range of communities including social and computer scientists, physicists, and interdisciplinary researchers. Despite substantial theoretical and practical achievements, unification and comparison of different approaches are lacking, which impedes further advances. In this article, we review recent developments in recommender systems and discuss the major challenges. We compare and evaluate available algorithms and examine their roles in the future developments. In addition to algorithms, physical aspects are described to illustrate macroscopic behavior of recommender systems. Potential impacts and future directions are discussed. We emphasize that recommendation has great scientific depth and combines diverse research fields which makes it interesting for physicists as well as interdisciplinary researchers.},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2022-12-21},
    journal = {Physics Reports},
    author = {Lü, Linyuan and Medo, Matúš and Yeung, Chi Ho and Zhang, Yi-Cheng and Zhou, Tao},
    month = oct,
    year = {2012},
    keywords = {Information filtering, Networks, Recommender systems},
    pages = {1--49},
    file = {ScienceDirect Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\Agh\\Zotero\\storage\\QCE53MUG\\S0370157312000828.html:text/html;Version acceptée:C\:\\Users\\Agh\\Zotero\\storage\\KX7HTGET\\Lü et al. - 2012 - Recommender systems.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking `\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}` should be `\bibliography{bibliographie}`, since `\bibliography` takes the file name without extension, but I think most BibTeX implementations nowadays should just ignore this. Can you tell us what exactly BibTeX complains about? Just post the complete `.blg` file here-.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue, because you use `\input`, but BibTeX is one of those old-fashioned tools that doesn't like spaces in file names, so maybe keep that in mind for future developments in your project when you name your subfolders.

Comment: Also unlikely to be the issue, but since your are using BibTeX, which can only deal with ASCII characters, you need to escape non-ASCII chars such as `ü`, `ú` and `š` to `{\"u}`, `{\'u}` and `{\v S}` for proper sorting. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864.

Comment: using spaces in directory names makes everything much harder