# Special characters (such as é, ç, ü) in .bib file using citation-style-language

Tags: bibliographies, csl

I am using `citation-style-language` package on Overleaf with Luatex to cite references as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style=vancouver}

\addbibresource{paperpile.bib}

\title{csl timeout minimal}
\author{Minoru Matsui}
\date{July 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\cite{Matsui2023-lk}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with the .bib file of `paperpile.bib` as

```
@MISC{Matsui2023-lk,
  title        = "test",
  author       = "åüéç Jaromír Kovářík, Surname",
  year         =  2023,
}
%% the following does not work
@comment{
@MISC{Matsui2023-lk,
  title        = "test",
  author       = "{\"a} {\^e} ,{\`i} {\.I} {\o} {\'u} {\aa} {\c c} {\u g} {\l} {\~n} {\H o} {\v r} {\ss} {\r u}",
  year         =  2023,
}
}
```

which produces ↓

[image]

The problem is that I cannot make it work when I comment out the former part and use the latter commented-out section. I want to use the latter way of formatting special characters because

1. Paperpile exports .bib file as such, and
2. My understanding is that I [should not use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/how-to-write-%C3%A4-and-other-umlauts-and-accented-letters-in-bibliography) special characters such as ü directly in .bib file.

To explain the situation more precisely, the compile timeouts on Overleaf (try it yourself [here](https://ja.overleaf.com/read/ghqrhphsygkx)). What am I doing wrong? Should I specify the character encoding as UTF-8? Should I load another package or something? I understand that the package is still in its early stage. Should I submit an issue to [their repo](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues)?

Comment: I've just tried this on an up-to-date TeX Live 2023, and it works other than an issue with a `hyperref` command (which I suspect is unrelated). As this is very developmental code, I suspect it might be that the Overleaf version is too old to do what you want. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the `File list` that appears in the `.log` file?

Comment: The documentation of `\addbibresource` in the user manual notes: *”Note that only UTF-8 encoding is supported in the ⟨resource⟩ file.”* So IMHO you *should* use UTF-8 for the bib file with `citation-style-language` (BTW: with `biblatex` IMHO this would also be best).

Comment: @cabohah I think that's talking about other input encodings, not LICR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @josephwright pointed out, the `citation-style-language` package from Overleaf (TeX Live 2022) was is old (v0.1.0) and the latest released version is 0.4.1 (2023-04-12). The BibTeX (.bib) parser within it was completely rewritten in v0.2.1 (2022-09-18) to support LaTeX diacritics.

Since Overleaf provides no way to update the packages, I suggest uploading all the `.sty` and `.lua` files from the latest development version to the project and it compiles successfully (see https://www.overleaf.com/read/dkjqrmwbmfqy).

The mentioned `hyperref`-related issue is caused by LaTeX2e 2023-06-01 kernel's change and it has been fixed in the development version ([zepinglee/citeproc-lua@db0af89](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/commit/db0af89cd3835604a58747670db4d5268f9926ba)).