# invalid utf-8 sequence error from .bib file despite valid character in main document

Tags: bibtex, unicode

I'm working on a paper `main.tex` with a separate Bibtex file `references.bib`. I compile with:

```
lualatex main
bibtex main
lualatex main
```

(Note that I must use `bibtex` because the journal style is not compatible with `biber`)

In the last step 'lualatex main', I obtain the error `String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence` which comes from a reference in the Bibtex file: one of the authors names starts with character `Á` (the error does not happen if this character is removed).

I'm confused: the character seems to be [valid utf-8](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00C1), and it prints without any issue if it's inside the main document. Additionally my Bibtex file contains other uncommon accentuated characters which are displayed normally in the pdf.

What am I missing?

---

Sorry, I omitted to show the offending entry in the bibtex file:

```
@book {walsh15,
      author = {Walsh, Kieran and Carney, Gemma M. and Ní Léime, Áine},
      title = "Ageing through Austerity: Critical Perspectives from Ireland",
      year = "2015",
      publisher = "Policy Press",
      address = "Bristol, UK",
      isbn = "9781447316251",
      doi = "10.51952/9781447316251",
      url = "https://bristoluniversitypressdigital.com/view/book/9781447316251/9781447316251.xml"
}
```

and the resulting .bbl entry:

```
%Type = Book
\bibitem[{Walsh et~al.(2015)Walsh, Carney and Ní~Léime}]{walsh15}
\bibinfo{author}{Walsh, K.}, \bibinfo{author}{Carney, G.M.},
  \bibinfo{author}{Ní~Léime, \C3.}, \bibinfo{year}{2015}.
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Ageing through Austerity: Critical Perspectives from
  Ireland}.
\newblock \bibinfo{publisher}{Policy Press}, \bibinfo{address}{Bristol, UK}.
\newblock \URLprefix
  \url{https://bristoluniversitypressdigital.com/view/book/9781447316251/9781447316251.xml},
  \DOIprefix\doi{10.51952/9781447316251}.
```

And here is the error message:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.362   \bibinfo{author}{Ní~Léime, 
                                   �..}, \bibinfo{year}{2015}.
```

Comment: hard to say with no code shown. The most common reason for getting that error is the file does in fact have an incorrectly encoded character.

Comment: show at least the generated bbl for that entry and the full error from the log which will show the error context

Comment: See pages 3-4 in [http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf)

Comment: My guess is you have an `Á` in some place that BibTeX is doing case changing or similar: that will go wrong and the output is then likely invalid - but like @DavidCarlisle says, we need an example

Comment: bibtex doesn't like utf8 at the begin of name. It tries to split it for the initial.

Comment: use `{\'A}` not `Á`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works now, thank you very much!

Comment: For more information on how to enter "accented" characters in a bib file, please see [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bibtex knows nothing about multi-byte encodings so while trying to fine the "Inital letter" of the name it pulls out just one byte of the bytes for `Á` so ends up with an invalid generated latex `.bbl` file.  `{\'A}` is the documented bibtex syntax, and keeps everything ascii.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to replace accented characters in the bibliography, I suggest you run `bibtexu` -- where "u" denotes either unicode or utf8 -- instead of "plain" `bibtex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
@book{walsh15,
      author = {Walsh, Kieran and Carney, Gemma M. and Ní Léime, Áine},
      title = "Ageing through Austerity: Critical Perspectives from Ireland",
      year = "2015",
      publisher = "Policy Press",
      address = "Bristol, UK",
      isbn = "9781447316251",
      doi = "10.51952/9781447316251",
      url = "https://bristoluniversitypressdigital.com/view/book/9781447316251/9781447316251.xml"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\cite{walsh15}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested bibtexu for the companion and found to many bugs to include it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - It's a real pity that `bibtexu` isn't up to snuff in terms of bugginess.